# Should you always favor xrange() over range()?

Tags: python, range, xrange

Why or why not?

Comment: Can someone briefly describe the difference between the 2 for us non-python guys?  Maybe something like "xrange() does everyhing range() does, but also supports X, Y, and Z"

Comment: range(n) creates a list containing all the integers 0..n-1. This is a problem if you do range(1000000), because you'll end up with a >4Mb list. xrange deals with this by returning an object that pretends to be a list, but just works out the number needed from the index asked for, and returns that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/

Comment: Basically, whereas `range(1000)` is a `list`, `xrange(1000)` is an object that acts like a `generator` (although it certainly is *not* one). Also, `xrange` is faster. You can `import timeit from timeit` and then make a method that just has `for i in xrange: pass` and another for `range`, then do `timeit(method1)` and `timeit(method2)` and, lo and behold, xrange is almost twice as fast sometimes (that is when you don't need a list). (For me, for `i in xrange(1000):pass` vs for `i in range(1000):pass` took `13.316725969314575` vs `21.190124988555908` seconds respectively - that's a lot.)

Comment: [Another performance test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30545536/1143274) gives `xrange(100)` as 20% faster than `range(100)`.

Answer (score 447, accepted):

For performance, especially when you're iterating over a large range, `xrange()` is usually better.  However, there are still a few cases why you might prefer `range()`:

- In python 3, `range()` does what `xrange()` used to do and `xrange()` does not exist.  If you want to write code that will run on both Python 2 and Python 3, you can't use `xrange()`.
- `range()` can actually be faster in some cases - eg. if iterating over the same sequence multiple times.  `xrange()` has to reconstruct the integer object every time, but `range()` will have real integer objects.  (It will always perform worse in terms of memory however)
- `xrange()` isn't usable in all cases where a real list is needed.  For instance, it doesn't support slices, or any list methods.

[Edit] There are a couple of posts mentioning how `range()` will be upgraded by the 2to3 tool.  For the record, here's the output of running the tool on some sample usages of `range()` and `xrange()`

```
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
--- range_test.py (original)
+++ range_test.py (refactored)
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@

 for x in range(20):
-    a=range(20)
+    a=list(range(20))
     b=list(range(20))
     c=[x for x in range(20)]
     d=(x for x in range(20))
-    e=xrange(20)
+    e=range(20)
```

As you can see, when used in a for loop or comprehension, or where already wrapped with list(), range is left unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean by "range will become an iterator"? Should this not be "generator"?

Comment: No. Generator refers to a specific type of iterator, and the new `range` isn't an iterator anyway.

Comment: Your second bullet doesn't really make any sense. You are saying that you can't use an object multiple times; sure you can! try `xr = xrange(1,11)` then on the next line `for i in xr: print " ".join(format(i*j,"3d") for j in xr)` and voila! You have your times-tables up to ten. It works just the same as `r = range(1,11)` and `for i in r: print " ".join(format(i*j,"3d") for j in r)`... everything is an object in Python2. I think what you meant to say is that you can do index-based comprehension (if that makes sense) better with `range` as opposed to `xrange`. Range is handy very seldom, I think

Comment: (Not enough room) Although, I *do* think that `range` can be handy if you want to use a `list` in a loop and then change certain indices based on certain conditions or append things to that list, then `range` is definitely better. However, `xrange` is simply faster and uses less memory, so for the majority of for loop applications, it appears to be the best. There are instances - going back to the questioner's question - seldom but existent, where `range` would be better. Perhaps not as seldom as I am thinking, but I certainly use `xrange` 95% of the time.

Answer (score 130):

No, they both have their uses:

Use `xrange()` when iterating, as it saves memory.  Say:

```
for x in xrange(1, one_zillion):
```

rather than:

```
for x in range(1, one_zillion):
```

On the other hand, use `range()` if you actually want a list of numbers.

```
multiples_of_seven = range(7,100,7)
print "Multiples of seven < 100: ", multiples_of_seven
```

Answer (score 42):

You should favour `range()` over `xrange()` only when you need an actual list. For instance, when you want to modify the list returned by `range()`, or when you wish to slice it. For iteration or even just normal indexing, `xrange()` will work fine (and usually much more efficiently). There is a point where `range()` is a bit faster than `xrange()` for very small lists, but depending on your hardware and various other details, the break-even can be at a result of length 1 or 2; not something to worry about. Prefer `xrange()`.

Answer (score 31):

One other difference is that Python 2 implementation of `xrange()` can't support numbers bigger than C ints, so if you want to have a range using Python's built in large number support, you have to use `range()`.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 13 2012, 22:29:01) 
[GCC 4.7.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> range(123456787676676767676676,123456787676676767676679)
[123456787676676767676676L, 123456787676676767676677L, 123456787676676767676678L]
>>> xrange(123456787676676767676676,123456787676676767676679)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Python 3 does not have this problem:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jul 14 2012, 01:01:48) 
[GCC 4.7.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> range(123456787676676767676676,123456787676676767676679)
range(123456787676676767676676, 123456787676676767676679)
```

Answer (score 13):

`xrange()` is more efficient because instead of generating a list of objects, it just generates one object at a time. Instead of 100 integers, and all of their overhead, and the list to put them in, you just have one integer at a time. Faster generation, better memory use, more efficient code.

Unless I specifically need a list for something, I always favor `xrange()`

Answer (score 8):

range() returns a list, xrange() returns an xrange object.

xrange() is a bit faster, and a bit more memory efficient. But the gain is not very large.

The extra memory used by a list is of course not just wasted, lists have more functionality (slice, repeat, insert, ...). Exact differences can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/typesseq.html). There is no bonehard rule, use what is needed.

Python 3.0 is still in development, but IIRC range() will very similar to xrange() of 2.X and list(range()) can be used to generate lists.

Answer (score 5):

I would just like to say that it REALLY isn't that difficult to get an xrange object with slice and indexing functionality.  I have written some code that works pretty dang well and is just as fast as xrange for when it counts (iterations).

```
from __future__ import division

def read_xrange(xrange_object):
    # returns the xrange object's start, stop, and step
    start = xrange_object[0]
    if len(xrange_object) > 1:
       step = xrange_object[1] - xrange_object[0]
    else:
        step = 1
    stop = xrange_object[-1] + step
    return start, stop, step

class Xrange(object):
    ''' creates an xrange-like object that supports slicing and indexing.
    ex: a = Xrange(20)
    a.index(10)
    will work

    Also a[:5]
    will return another Xrange object with the specified attributes

    Also allows for the conversion from an existing xrange object
    '''
    def __init__(self, *inputs):
        # allow inputs of xrange objects
        if len(inputs) == 1:
            test, = inputs
            if type(test) == xrange:
                self.xrange = test
                self.start, self.stop, self.step = read_xrange(test)
                return

        # or create one from start, stop, step
        self.start, self.step = 0, None
        if len(inputs) == 1:
            self.stop, = inputs
        elif len(inputs) == 2:
            self.start, self.stop = inputs
        elif len(inputs) == 3:
            self.start, self.stop, self.step = inputs
        else:
            raise ValueError(inputs)

        self.xrange = xrange(self.start, self.stop, self.step)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.xrange)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if type(item) is int:
            if item < 0:
                item += len(self)

            return self.xrange[item]

        if type(item) is slice:
            # get the indexes, and then convert to the number
            start, stop, step = item.start, item.stop, item.step
            start = start if start != None else 0 # convert start = None to start = 0
            if start < 0:
                start += start
            start = self[start]
            if start < 0: raise IndexError(item)
            step = (self.step if self.step != None else 1) * (step if step != None else 1)
            stop = stop if stop is not None else self.xrange[-1]
            if stop < 0:
                stop += stop

            stop = self[stop]
            stop = stop

            if stop > self.stop:
                raise IndexError
            if start < self.start:
                raise IndexError
            return Xrange(start, stop, step)

    def index(self, value):
        error = ValueError('object.index({0}): {0} not in object'.format(value))
        index = (value - self.start)/self.step
        if index % 1 != 0:
            raise error
        index = int(index)


        try:
            self.xrange[index]
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            raise error
        return index

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.xrange)
```

Honestly, I think the whole issue is kind of silly and xrange should do all of this anyway...

Comment: Yeah agreed; from a totally different technology, check the work on lodash to make it lazy: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/274. Slicing etc should still be as lazy as possible and where not, only then reify.

Answer (score 4):

Go with range for these reasons:

1) xrange will be going away in newer Python versions.  This gives you easy future compatibility.

2) range will take on the efficiencies associated with xrange.

Comment: Don't do this. xrange() will go away, but so will a lot of other things. The tool you will be using to translate your Python 2.x code into Python 3.x code will automatically translate xrange() to range(), but range() will be translated to the less efficient list(range()).

Comment: Thomas: Its actually a bit smarter than that. It'll translate range() in situations where it clearly doesn't need a real list (eg in a for loop, or comprehension) to just plain range(). Only cases where it gets assigned to a variable, or used directly must be wrapped with list()

Answer (score 4):

A good example given in book: [Practical Python](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=KmKoNJ2OoOYC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=zip%28range%285%29,%20xrange%28100000000%29%29&source=bl&ots=-BxWZinKHq&sig=O9G4mskHmYDljCCQv8v7alVUy_M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0mMPUoa9LsXJrAe7p4DABA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=zip%28range%285%29,%20xrange%28100000000%29%29&f=false) By Magnus Lie Hetland

```
>>> zip(range(5), xrange(100000000))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

I wouldn’t recommend using range instead of xrange in the preceding example—although
only the first five numbers are needed, range calculates all the numbers, and that may take a lot
of time. With xrange, this isn’t a problem because it calculates only those numbers needed.

Yes I read @Brian's answer: In python 3, range() is a generator anyway and xrange() does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

While `xrange` is faster than `range` in most circumstances, the difference in performance is pretty minimal. The little program below compares iterating over a `range` and an `xrange`:

```
import timeit
# Try various list sizes.
for list_len in [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
  # Time doing a range and an xrange.
  rtime = timeit.timeit('a=0;\nfor n in range(%d): a += n'%list_len, number=1000)
  xrtime = timeit.timeit('a=0;\nfor n in xrange(%d): a += n'%list_len, number=1000)
  # Print the result
  print "Loop list of len %d: range=%.4f, xrange=%.4f"%(list_len, rtime, xrtime)
```

The results below shows that `xrange` is indeed faster, but not enough to sweat over.

```
Loop list of len 1: range=0.0003, xrange=0.0003
Loop list of len 10: range=0.0013, xrange=0.0011
Loop list of len 100: range=0.0068, xrange=0.0034
Loop list of len 1000: range=0.0609, xrange=0.0438
Loop list of len 10000: range=0.5527, xrange=0.5266
Loop list of len 100000: range=10.1666, xrange=7.8481
Loop list of len 1000000: range=168.3425, xrange=155.8719
```

So by all means use `xrange`, but unless you're on a constrained hardware, don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Your `list_len` is not being used and so you're only running this code for lists of length 100.

Comment: I'd recommend actually modifying the list length: `rtime = timeit.timeit('a=0;\nfor n in range(%d): a += n' % list_len, number=1000)`

Comment: Wow, this is shaping up to be a good week, thanks, fixed. Still, not a major difference.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, everyone here as a different opinion as to the tradeoffs and advantages of xrange versus range.  They're mostly correct, xrange is an iterator, and range fleshes out and creates an actual list.  For the majority of cases, you won't really notice a difference between the two.  (You can use map with range but not with xrange, but it uses up more memory.)

What I think you rally want to hear, however, is that the preferred choice is xrange.  Since range in Python 3 is an iterator, the code conversion tool 2to3 will correctly convert all uses of xrange to range, and will throw out an error or warning for uses of range.  If you want to be sure to easily convert your code in the future, you'll use xrange only, and list(xrange) when you're sure that you want a list.  I learned this during the CPython sprint at PyCon this year (2008) in Chicago.

Comment: Thats not true.  Code like "for x in range(20)" will be left as range, and code like "x=range(20)" will be converted to "x=list(range(20))" - no errors.  Further, if you want to write code that will run under both 2.6 and 3.0, range() is your only option without adding compatability functions.

Answer (score 2):

- `range()`: `range(1, 10)` returns a list from 1 to 10 numbers & hold whole list in memory.
- `xrange()`: Like `range()`, but instead of returning a list, returns an object that generates the numbers in the range on demand. For looping, this is lightly faster than `range()` and more memory efficient. `xrange()` object like an iterator and generates the numbers on demand (Lazy Evaluation).

```
In [1]: range(1,10)
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [2]: xrange(10)
Out[2]: xrange(10)

In [3]: print xrange.__doc__
Out[3]: xrange([start,] stop[, step]) -> xrange object
```

`range()` does the same thing as `xrange()` used to do in Python 3 and there is not term `xrange()` exist in Python 3.
`range()` can actually be faster in some scenario if you iterating over the same sequence multiple times. `xrange()` has to reconstruct the integer object every time, but `range()` will have real integer objects.