# python simple iteration

Tags: python, iteration

i would like to ask what is the best way to make simple iteration. suppose i want to repeat certain task 1000 times, which one of the following is the best? or is there a better way?

```
for i in range(1000):
    do something with no reference to i

i = 0
while i < 1000:
    do something with no reference to i
    i += 1
```

thanks very much

Comment: I prefer the first one ... I believe it's just a matter of personal taste

Comment: The first one is more idiomatic.

Comment: "which one of the following is the best"?  What do **you** mean by "best"?  Please define "best".  Without a definition for "best" either of these could be better.  Indeed, there are yet more ways to do this, which -- depending on your definition of "best" -- could be best.  Please define "best".

Comment: Oh, and did I mention, please define best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is considered idiomatic. In Python 2.x, use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: +1 for `xrange`, which has almost the exact same performance characteristics (at least in the CPython implementation).

Comment: is xrange() always better than range() ? when should one use range() instead of xrange()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range

Comment: In 2.x, `range()` creates the list of numbers ahead of time, iterates through it, and then throws it away. `xrange()` (`range()` in 3.x) creates a special "generator" object that  returns the numbers on demand, which is more efficient. In 3.x, if you actually want the list, you must ask for it: e.g. `list(xrange(10))` will use the list constructor to make a list out of the values returned from the generator.

Comment: See also my answer with figures

Answer (score 6):

The `for` loop is more concise and more readable. while loops are rarely used in Python (with the exception of `while True`).

A bit of idiomatic Python: if you're trying to do something a set number of times with a range (with no need to use the counter), it's good practice to name the counter `_`. Example:

```
for _ in range(1000):
    # do something 1000 times
```

Comment: Personally I would never use `_` for a loop but always `i`, `j`, `k`. In the interactive console, `_`  is the previous result, and in programs `_` will often be used for i18n (much less than in other languages as `_` *is* seen more as a throwaway variable in Python).

Comment: @Chris Agreed for the interactive interpreter. As for localization, I've never seen that in any language.

Comment: haven't seen `_('string')`? It's a common usage pattern with gettext.

Comment: @Chris nope, or maybe I never noticed it

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2, use

```
for i in xrange(1000):
    pass
```

In Python 3, use

```
for i in range(1000):
    pass
```

Performance figures for Python 2.6:

```
$ python -s -m timeit '' 'i = 0
> while i < 1000:
>     i += 1'
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.1 usec per loop

$ python -s -m timeit '' 'for i in range(1000): pass'
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.8 usec per loop

$ python -s -m timeit '' 'for i in xrange(1000): pass'
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.9 usec per loop
```

`xrange` is preferable to `range` in this case because it produces a generator rather than the whole list `[0, 1, 2, ..., 998, 999]`. It'll use less memory, too. If you needed the actual list to work with all at once, that's when you use `range`. Normally you want `xrange`: that's why in Python 3, `xrange(...)` becomes `range(...)` and `range(...)` becomes `list(range(...))`.

Comment: On my system, `range` continues to perform more or less linearly up to about 130,000 elements or so, and then takes a big jump in time/loop/iteration and continues to get worse. `xrange` is unstoppable up to at least a hundred million elements, and I would only expect it to start showing any kind of slowdown at all somewhere around the 2-4 billion mark. ;)

Answer (score 0):

first. because the integer is done in the internal layer rather than interpretor. Also one less global variable.