# How to set ranges of rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following working code that sets 1 to "new_col" at the locations pointed by intervals dictated by `starts` and `ends`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(10)})

starts = [1, 5, 8]
ends = [1, 6, 10]

value = 1
df["new_col"] = 0

for s, e in zip(starts, ends):
    df.loc[s:e, "new_col"] = value

print(df)
```

> ```
>    a  new_col
> 0  0        0
> 1  1        1
> 2  2        0
> 3  3        0
> 4  4        0
> 5  5        1
> 6  6        1
> 7  7        0
> 8  8        1
> 9  9        1
> ```

I want these intervals to come from another dataframe `pointer_df`.

**How to vectorize this?**

```
pointer_df = pd.DataFrame({"starts": starts, "ends": ends})
```

Attempt:

```
df.loc[pointer_df["starts"]:pointer_df["ends"], "new_col"] = 2
print(df)
```

obviously doesn't work and gives

> ```
>     raise AssertionError("Start slice bound is non-scalar")
> AssertionError: Start slice bound is non-scalar
> ```

---

EDIT:

it seems all answers use some kind of pythonic for loop.

the question was how to vectorize the operation above?

Is this not doable without for loops/list comprehentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
pointer_df = pd.DataFrame({"starts": starts, "ends": ends})

rang = np.arange(len(df))
indices = [i for s, e in pointer_df.to_numpy() for i in rang[slice(s, e + 1, None)]]

df.loc[indices, 'new_col'] = value
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   a  new_col
0  0        0
1  1        1
2  2        0
3  3        0
4  4        0
5  5        1
6  6        1
7  7        0
8  8        1
9  9        1
```

If you want a method that do not uses uses any for loop or list comprehension, only relies on numpy, you could do:

```
def indices(start, end, ma=10):
    limits = end + 1
    lens = np.where(limits < ma, limits, end) - start
    np.cumsum(lens, out=lens)
    i = np.ones(lens[-1], dtype=int)
    i[0] = start[0]
    i[lens[:-1]] += start[1:]
    i[lens[:-1]] -= limits[:-1]
    np.cumsum(i, out=i)
    return i


pointer_df = pd.DataFrame({"starts": starts, "ends": ends})
df.loc[indices(pointer_df.starts.values, pointer_df.ends.values, ma=len(df)), "new_col"] = value
print(df)
```

I adapted the method to your use case from the one in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708737/4001592).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,j in zip(pointer_df["starts"],pointer_df["ends"]):
    print (i,j)
```

Apply same method but on your dictionary

Comment: this is just a copy paste of what I did, just doesn't solve the problem