# Modifying list elements in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a list `a` for which I want to change the elements `a[i: j]` according to a function `f`. Can I do better than the naive way?

```
for index in range(i, j):
    a[index] = f(a)
```

[By better I mean something closer to `map(f, a)`, or something faster.]

Comment: You might prefer `xrange` over `range` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/135114/589206).

Comment: I think this is closer to your intent: `for index, ai in enumerate(a[i:j], start=i):
    a[index] = f(ai)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign to the slice:

```
a[i:j] = map(f, a[i:j])
```

Comment: @Randomblue read up on slices. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types "`s[i:j] = t` slice of s from i to j is replaced by the contents of the iterable t"

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to do timing exercises but I'll show you what internal code the various options turn into. Your code is `naive`. The map-based solution with the slice as l-value is `map_lvalue_slice`. The list comprehension with the slice as l-value is `list_comp_lvalue_slice`. A solution related to the list comprehension uses a tuple and is called `tuple_lvalue_slice`:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> 
>>> def naive(a, f, i, j):
...     for index, ai in enumerate(a[i:j], start=i):
...         a[index] = f(ai)
... 
>>> def map_lvalue_slice(a, f, i, j):
...     a[i:j] = map(f, a[i:j])
... 
>>> def list_comp_lvalue_slice(a, f, i, j):
...     a[i:j] = [f(ai) for ai in a[i:j]]
... 
>>> def tuple_lvalue_slice(a, f, i, j):
...     a[i:j] = tuple(f(ai) for ai in a[i:j])
... 
>>> dis(naive)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              55 (to 58)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (enumerate)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             12 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             15 SLICE+3             
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 ('start')
             19 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION          257
             25 GET_ITER            
        >>   26 FOR_ITER                28 (to 57)
             29 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             32 STORE_FAST               4 (index)
             35 STORE_FAST               5 (ai)

  3          38 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             41 LOAD_FAST                5 (ai)
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             47 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             50 LOAD_FAST                4 (index)
             53 STORE_SUBSCR        
             54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           26
        >>   57 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   58 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             61 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> 
>>> dis(map_lvalue_slice)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (map)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             12 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             15 SLICE+3             
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             22 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             25 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             28 STORE_SLICE+3       
             29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> 
>>> dis(list_comp_lvalue_slice)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
              9 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             12 SLICE+3             
             13 GET_ITER            
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                18 (to 35)
             17 STORE_FAST               4 (ai)
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             23 LOAD_FAST                4 (ai)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             29 LIST_APPEND              2
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
        >>   35 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             38 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             41 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             44 STORE_SLICE+3       
             45 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             48 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> 
>>> dis(tuple_lvalue_slice)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (tuple)
              3 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (f)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0xb748dc38, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             21 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             24 SLICE+3             
             25 GET_ITER            
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             29 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             32 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             35 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             38 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             41 STORE_SLICE+3       
             42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE
```

The solutions that resolve fastest to C code, preferably in a tight loop, are most desirable in my opinion because they are likely using mostly optimized C code and not predominantly interpreted instructions. I'd prefer the slice as l-value solutions over your code and I might lean towards to the map solution even though I am mostly a list comprehension guy.

Also, here is the proof that they are equivalent code:

```
>>> i, j = 4, 8
>>> def f(ai):
...     return -ai
... 
>>> for fn in (naive, map_lvalue_slice, list_comp_lvalue_slice, tuple_lvalue_slice):
...     a = range(10)
...     fn(a, f, i, j)
...     print "%-40s: %r" % (fn.__name__, a)
... 
naive                                   : [0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9]
map_lvalue_slice                        : [0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9]
list_comp_lvalue_slice                  : [0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9]
tuple_lvalue_slice                      : [0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension...

```
a[i:j] = [f(ai) for ai in a[i:j]]
```

or the `map` equivalent...

```
a[i:j] = map(f, a[i:j])
```

Comment: You should test it on your use case. It will depend, probably, on the values of i and j and the types of the elements.