# Modify list values in a "for loop"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'am trying to clip the values in arrays. I found the function `np.clip()`
and it did what I need. However, the way it modifies the array values in the list of arrays makes me confused. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
b = np.arange(5)

for x in [a,b]:
    np.clip(x, 1, 3, out=x)
```

result

```
>>> a
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
>>> b
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

The values of `a` and `b` have been changed without being assigned while the function `np.clip()` only works with `x`.

There are some questions related, but they use index of the list, e.g [Modifying list elements in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304302/modifying-list-elements-in-a-for-loop), [Changing iteration variable inside for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902835/changing-iteration-variable-inside-for-loop-in-python).

Can somebody explain for me how the function `np.clip()` can directly modify the value of list values.

Comment: The loop applied `clip` first to `a`, and 2nd iteration to `b`

Comment: I know that `clip` must do something to `a` and `b`, but in the loop it is `x` that represents and being the input of `clip`. And no more value assign like `a = np.clip(x,1,3,out=x)`. That's why I am confused :(

Comment: @HaBom Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: During the loop `x` first references the same array as `a` and then `b`.  The effect is same as `np.clilp(a,1,3,out=a)` and then `np.clip(b,1,3,out=b)`.  A `for` loop on a range or list of numbers can't modify the list, but a loop on a list of 'mutables' can modify those elements.  It may help to `print(x)` inside the loop.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks you guys

Comment: @hpaulj can you put your comment to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the `np.clip` function. It's because you use loop on a list of mutable, so the value of the element can be modified. You can see here [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types) for more information.