# what is the cleanest way to loop in a range of numbers in python?

Tags: python

So lets say

```
start = 10
end = 30
```

now I need a loop that goes from `start`to `end`

I was thinking of something like this:

```
for i in [start..end]
  print i
```

but that does not quite work. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious, how can you put together a page like https://sites.google.com/site/pythonmemory/ and not know about range()?

Comment: @NedBatchelder I'm more of a low level, c/compiler person. I don't have much experience coding in python, but I do know (somewhat) what is going on underneath the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in range(start, end+1):
   print i
```

will give you the output from 10 to *inclusive* 30.

NOTE: The reason I added `+1` to your `end` value is because the [range()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function specifies a *half-closed interval*. This means the first value is *included*, but the end value is *not*.

I.e.,

```
  range(5, 10)
```

would give you a list of

```
  5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

but *not* include 10.

You can also specify the step size for [range()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) and a host of other things, see the [documenation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range).

Finally, if you are using Python 2.x you can also use [xrange()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) in place of `range()`, though in Python 3.x you will only have `range()` which is why I used it here.

If you are curious about the differences between `range()` and `xrange()` (though it is not really directly relevant to your question) the following two SO questions are a good place to start: [What is the difference between range and xrange functions in Python 2.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange) and [Should you always favor xrange() over range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in xrange(start, end + 1):
    print i
```

Use `range` in `xrange`’s stead (as @Levon suggests) if you are using Python 3, as opposed to Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in xrange(10, 31):
   # something
```

Look at the fine manual, it'll explain it for you... Note that the ending point is "up to, but not including" - it's called a half closed range.

Also as others have mentioned in Python 3.x - `range()` is a generator and doesn't create a `list` as in Python 2.x. However, the 2to3 tool will automatically convert an `xrange` to a `range` statement.

In 2.x `range` generated a physical list which can be sliced etc... But in 3.x you have to write `list(range(1000))` if you want it to materialise what it did in 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `range()`

```
range(start,end) #end not inclusive
range(end) # starts with 0,end not inclusive
range(start, end, step) #increments of step, default = 1
```

For example,

```
for i in range(100,150):
   print i
```

**Note:** Py3k+ has only range(), prior versions have `xrange()` and `range()`, both are similar except `xrange()` is a generator, whereas `range()` creates a list of the numbers which you can iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate and print each element of the list. Try the following:

```
for i in range(start,end+1):
print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also print the full range of numbers by printing the resulting list returned from range:

```
print(range(start, end+1))
```