# PyQt: QTableWidget to .xls file

Tags: python, pyqt, xls, qtablewidget

So, I have a QTableWidget that I want to save it to an .xls file using the xlwt module...

Here's the code:

```
def savefile(self):
        filename = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))    
        wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
        self.sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet")
        self.row = 0
        self.col = 0
        self.add2(self.row, self.col)
        wbk.save(filename)    


def add2(self, row, col):
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        for x in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            try:
                teext = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
                self.sheet.write(row, col, teext)
                row += 1
            except AttributeError:
                pass                   
        col += 1
```

But that writes out only the text from cell 0,0 and nothing else...

I think that I have made some serious mistake...

**Update:**

```
def savefile(self):
        filename = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))    
        wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
        self.sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        self.add2()
        wbk.save(filename)    


def add2(self):
    row = 0
    col = 0         
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        for x in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            try:             
                teext = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
                self.sheet.write(row, col, teext)
                row += 1
            except AttributeError:
                row += 1
        row = 0
        col += 1
```

Solved the problem...

Comment: Question for you-- with the self.tableWidget.item(row,col).text()), I get a "NoneType" error that object has no value "text".  Any ideas?  Thanks for posting this-- immensely helpful!

Comment: Maybe it's because there was no text to one particular cell, use "try:" and "except NoneTypeError:" and tell me what you get... By the way, did you convert it to string? Well, I don't get any errors like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also find it more concise and easier to use the output of the range (or [xrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range)) as the indexes for your tableWidget.item call rather than worrying about incrementing your own counters. You might be using the sheet itself in other places in code, but if you're not, it would save you some memory to not assign the sheet to be an attribute variable of your class:

```
def savefile(self):
    filename = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))    
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    self.add2(sheet)
    wbk.save(filename)

def add2(self, sheet):
    for currentColumn in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        for currentRow in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            try:
                teext = str(self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, currentColumn).text()
                sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, teext)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
```

Because you are using the range command, the currentColumn variable will increment from 0 to columnCount() and currentRow will increment from 0 to currentRow()