# Python Segfault, from range?

Tags: python, recursion

So i am trying to generate primes less than 2000000 and find their sum..  For a sample size I tried primes to 40000, but got a Segmentation Fault.  I tried many values and I find the number 35044 to be the crashing point of the program.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000000)
def stuff(total, rnge):
    for n in rnge:
        ubound=int(n**0.5)+1
        print ubound
        for x in range(3, ubound, 2):
            if n % x == 0:
                stuff(total, range(n+2, 35044, 2))
        #print n
        total = total + n
            #print total
    print total
    exit()
stuff(17, range(11, 35044, 2))
```

This is the error that results: `"Run Command: line 1:  2942 Segmentation fault: 11  python "$1" "${@:3}"`
Side note:  Finder also says python crashed and gives me a crash report, including these two bits of interesting info:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff5f3fffb8
```

Not sure if this is useful.

Also, for those who are wondering, I am on the latest 15-inch rMPB with 16 GB RAM and 2.7 Ghz processor, when I run the program eat eats up all 14GB or something of free RAM then crashes after it prints the number 181 a few times.

Comment: Works fine for me. I think you should add the details of your platform etc ...

Comment: unless this is in python 3, use `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: Even though you've set a very high limit on recursion, python is still limited by the size of its process' stack. It sounds like you've found the hard limit.

Comment: @Smac89 agree, and the recursive call `stuff(total, range(n+2, 35044, 2))` is likely creating a huge number of quite large lists. Fixing `stuff` to use xrange would be a much better implementation in terms of memory/stack usage.

Comment: Your function and variable names are terrible. How exactly is this code working?

Comment: @Smac89 What is the difference between xrange and range?

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr its working because I can name functions/variables whatever I want if there is no confliction

Comment: @icehockey38

See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/135669/2089675)

Comment: @Smac89 Si do I just replace all range with xrange, because it still crashes as it did before, or do i change other things

Comment: @icehockey38


From the description of your problem, it seems that even your ram is being exhausted by this program. I would suggest scrapping this idea and going with one of the answers below. Or find an iterative method for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no reason to use recursion as you  run into stack issues like you've discovered, especially if your target language doesn't support tail-call optimisation - like Python.

This is an alternate, really naive implementation (*O(n^2)*), but it does so without recursion so it can be used to sum any number of primes, albeit ever slowly as the candidate window get larger.

```
from math import sqrt    
total = 1+2
for i in range(3,2000000):
    for j in range (2,int(sqrt(i)+1)):
        if i%j==0:break
    else:
        total+=i
print total
```

Comment: Off by 1? Usually one isn't considered a prime, but it's being included in the initial value of `total` for some reason. Otherwise this is a good answer!

Comment: @Blckknght Yeah I guess that could be it. Easy enough to fix though.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes as it turns it it was off by one, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be possible that the recursive calls to your function are exhausting the available memory of your system?

Comment: Not the recursion, the `range` calls. This is obviously python2, and OP is creating two huge ranges with every recursion. The recursion overhead itself is likely a very minor factor.

Comment: @l4mpi so how do i fix this then?

Comment: @icehockey38 the simplest change would be using [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of range, as Smac89 commented on your question two days ago. Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange), "The xrange type is an immutable sequence which is commonly used for looping. The advantage of the xrange type is that an xrange object will always take the same amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents." Please learn how to use google to look up these things yourself...