# Looking for alternative, more pythonic, way to iterate over multiple characters on a string

Tags: python, loops, iteration

The simple and reliable way to "select" units, doubles, trinities etc.. of a string as you already know is this:

```
somestr = 'ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD'  
a = 0  
z = 3  
for i in somestr:  
    i = somestr[a:z]  
    # finally here i can work with with these 3 first characters of the somestr
    a += 1  # or 3 for non-overlapping
    z += 1
```

So my question is how could someone simplify this block of code according to the rules of python.
I'm interested in both overlapping and non-overlapping cases.

Comment: See [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443) for the non-overlapping case. Simply use `xrange(0, len(l) - n)` for the overlapping version.

Comment: You don't really need both `a` and `z` here since `z = a + constant`.

Comment: what is the difference between range and xrange ?

Comment: @fractal_7 - Here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can do this job nice and easily:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> somestr = 'ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD'
>>> # no overlapping
>>> for i in findall(".{3}", somestr):
...     print(i)
...
ABC
DAB
CDA
BCD
ABC
DAB
CDA
BCD
>>> # overlapping
>>> for i in findall("(?=(.{3}))", somestr):
...     print(i)
...
ABC
BCD
CDA
DAB
ABC
BCD
CDA
DAB
ABC
BCD
CDA
DAB
ABC
BCD
CDA
DAB
ABC
BCD
CDA
DAB
ABC
BCD
>>>
```

Note that I had it set to work with groups of `3`.  You can pick any number though.

Comment: ok i think this is by far the simplest way, i was about to choose the solution of jonrsharpe but this one with findall is even more simple since you don't have to mind about the limits.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `range` function includes a step argument, so for the simplest case you can do:

```
for i in range(0, len(somestring) - 3, 3):
    somestring[i:i+3]
```

You could create a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) as follows:

```
def substring_generator(string, length, overlap=True):
    for i in range(0, len(string) - length + 1, 1 if overlap else length):
        yield string[i:i+length]
```

And use this for both cases:

```
>>> print([x for x in substring_generator("ABCDEFG", 3, True)])
['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF', 'EFG']
>>> print([x for x in substring_generator("ABCDEFG", 3, False)])
['ABC', 'DEF']
```

Comment: that substring generator seems to be exactly what i need.
but i think it should be range(0, len(string) - lenght-1
not lenght+1. can you confirm it? i just checked

Comment: It's definitely +1, otherwise you don't get to the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

This allows you to:

```
>>> [''.join(item) for item in grouper(somestr, 3)]
['ABC', 'DAB', 'CDA', 'BCD', 'ABC', 'DAB', 'CDA', 'BCD']
>>> [''.join(item) for item in grouper(somestr, 4)]
['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'ABCD', 'ABCD', 'ABCD', 'ABCD']
```

Note that you need a `fillvalue` when the last string wouldn't have enough characters:

```
>>> [''.join(item) for item in grouper(somestr, 5, fillvalue='')]
['ABCDA', 'BCDAB', 'CDABC', 'DABCD', 'ABCD']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with chunks of data is `itertools.izip`:

```
from itertools import izip

def chunks(iterable, size=2):
  it = iter(iterable)
  return izip(*[it]*size)
```

Comment: This returns tuples of individual characters, not substrings.

Comment: Agreed.  It was a demonstration of approach, more than fully implemented code.

Answer (score 1):

```
how_many = 3
every_other = 3
three_at_a_time_skipping_three = [somestr[somestr.index(x):somestr.index(x)+how_many] for x in somestr[::every_other]]
#this pretty much means from where you started till 'how many' you want each time, while incrementing starting point by 'every_other'
print(three_at_a_time_skipping_three)
['ABC', 'DAB', 'CDA', 'BCD', 'ABC', 'DAB', 'CDA', 'BCD']

how_many = 4
four_at_a_time_skipping_three = [somestr[somestr.index(x):somestr.index(x)+how_many] for x in somestr[::every_other]]
print(four_at_a_time_skipping_three)
['ABCD', 'DABC', 'CDAB', 'BCDA', 'ABCD', 'DABC', 'CDAB', 'BCDA']
```

adjusting `how_many` and `every_other` will give you various results.

This is super ugly and super unreadable, but the general gist of it is, it uses slicing in `somestr` using the location of the item its iterating over. the `[::every_other]` is telling it to skip that many in the `somestr`.