# Insert values into SQL column with mysql-python

Tags: mysql, list, python-2.7, sql-update, mysql-python

I am trying to insert values into a column of a SQL table, using MySQLdb in Python 2.7. I am having problems with the command to insert a list into 1 column.

I have a simple table called 'name' as shown below:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+
| nameid | firstname | lastname | TopAdd |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 1      | Cookie    | Monster  |        |
| 2      | Guy       | Smiley   |        |
| 3      | Big       | Bird     |        |
| 4      | Oscar     | Grouch   |        |
| 5      | Alastair  | Cookie   |        |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Here is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `name` (
  `nameid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TopAdd` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nameid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is how I populated the table:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`name`
(`firstname`,`lastname`)
VALUES
("Cookie","Monster"),
("Guy","Smiley"),
("Big","Bird"),
("Oscar","Grouch"),
("Alastair","Cookie");
```

DISCLAIMER: The original source for the above MySQL example is [here](https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-python/).

Here is how I created the a new column named TopAdd:

```
ALTER TABLE name ADD TopAdd VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
```

I now have a list of 5 values that I would like to insert into the column TopAdd as the values of that column. Here is the list.

```
vals_list = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee']
```

Here is what I have tried (UPDATE statement inside loop):

```
vals = tuple(vals_list)
for self.ijk in range (0,len(self.vals)):
            self.cursor.execute ("UPDATE name SET TopAdd = %s WHERE 'nameid' = %s" % (self.vals[self.ijk],self.ijk+1))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\mySQLdbClass.py", line 70, in <module>
    [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]main()
  File "C:\Python27\mySQLdbClass.py", line 66, in main
    db.mysqlconnect()
  File "C:\Python27\mySQLdbClass.py", line 22, in mysqlconnect
    self.cursor.execute ("UPDATE name SET TopAdd = %s WHERE 'nameid' = %s" % (self.vals[self.ijk],self.ijk+1))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'aa' in 'field list'")
```

Is there a way to insert these values into the column with a loop or directly as a list?

Comment: You might want to fix the DDL in this question; your `INSERT` query will fail if the table is defined without a default value for `TopAdd`. Since you add that column later it looks like it shouldn't be included in the original `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
vals_list = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee']
```

for i, j in enumerate(vals_list):

```
 self.cursor.execute(("UPDATE test.name SET TopAdd = '%s' WHERE nameid = %s" % (str(j),int(i+1))
```

Comment: That worked! I do not understand how your method is working but mine is not. I tried this: `...% (str(self.vals_list[ijk]),int(ijk+1)))` but I am still getting the same error message. When I check the `type()` I get `<type 'str'> <type 'int'>` for my method. Using your method, `type()` gives me the same result. If that is the case, then my method should also work. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you changed  TopAdd ='%s' in your method, in your code it was TopAdd=%s

Comment: Thanks. You approach is a lot better. This answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is here:

```
for self.ijk in range (0,len(self.vals)):
```

The `range` function is creating a list of integers (presumably, the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`). When iterating over a collection in a `for` loop, you bind each successive item in the collection to a name; you do not *access them as attributes of an instance*. (It also seems appropriate to use `xrange` here; see [xrange vs range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135041/2359271).) So the `self` reference is non-sensical; beyond that, `ijk` is a terrible name for an integer value, and there's no need to supply the default start value of zero. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
for i in range(len(self.vals)):
```

Not only does this make your line shorter (and thus easier to read), using `i` to represent an integer value in a loop is a convention that's well understood. Now we come to another problem:

```
self.cursor.execute ("UPDATE name SET TopAdd = %s WHERE 'nameid' = %s" % (self.vals[self.ijk],self.ijk+1))
```

You're not properly parameterizing your query here. Do not follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27110404/2359271), which may fix your current error but leaves your code prone to wasted debugging time at best, [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) and/or data integrity issues at worst. Instead, replace the `%` with a comma so that the `execute` function does the work safely quoting and escaping parameters for you.

With that change, and minus the quotation marks around your column name, `nameid`:

```
query = "UPDATE name SET TopAdd = %s WHERE nameid = %s;"
for i in range(len(self.vals)):
    self.cursor.execute(query, (self.vals[i], i + 1))
```

Should work as expected. You can still use `enumerate` as suggested by the other answer, but there's no reason to go around typecasting everything in sight; enumerate is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and gives exactly the types you already want:

```
for i, val in enumerate(self.vals):
    self.cursor.execute(query, (val, i + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I marked the above answer as accepted, my final query ended up being very similar to the above answer and to yours(2nd one) - using `enumerate()`. I found this approach to be much more intuitive to understand than mine. Also, thank you for correcting me regarding my usage of `self()` - this was a real misunderstanding on my part and I can simplify code going forward. Thanks again.