# How to loop through 2D numpy array using x and y coordinates without getting out of bounds error?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
print a
rows = a.shape[0]
cols = a.shape[1]
print rows
print cols

for x in range(0, cols - 1):
    for y in range(0, rows -1):
        print a[x,y]
```

This only prints the numbers 1 through 6.

I have also tried only subtracting 1 from either rows or cols in the range, but that either leads to an out-of-bounds error or not all numbers being printed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`a.shape[0]` is the number of rows and the size of the first dimension, while `a.shape[1]` is the size of the second dimension. You need to write:

```
for x in range(0, rows):
    for y in range(0, cols):
        print a[x,y]
```

Note how rows and cols have been swapped in the `range()` function.

Edit: It has to be that way because an array can be rectangular (i.e. rows != cols). `a.shape` is the size of each dimension in the order they are indexed. Therefore if `shape` is `(10, 5)` when you write:

```
a[x, y]
```

the maximum x is 9 and the maximum y is 4.
`x` and `y` are actually poor names for array indices because they do not represent cartesian coordinates, but a location in memory. You can use i and j instead:

```
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        print a[i,j]
```

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) is a bit long but has a good, in-depth description of indices and shapes.

Comment: Right, the swapping has really been screwing me up lately. I don't understand why it has to be that way.

Answer (score 112):

**You get prettier code with:**

```
for iy, ix in np.ndindex(a.shape):
    print(a[iy, ix])
```

resulting in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: I got one question: Is this the most efficient method for accessing a value at index ix,iy? I'm trying to implement an image processing algorithm that's why I'm asking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali Ihsan Elmas: This is probably /surely not an efficient way for image processing. Use 'scipy.ndimage' and image filters instead. The functions 'convolve' and 'generic_filter' are interesting candidates to start with.

Comment: Prefer the order `iy, ix` for images and other cases where the fastest changing axis is semantically "X", if you still want to understand what's really happening.

Comment: @Christopher Bruns: you are right! I changed the arguments order in my answer to your proposal. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xrange`.

```
for x in xrange(rows):
    for y in xrange(cols):
        print a[x,y]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why using range(0, n) does not work? And what is the advantage to using xrange? Also, why does it seem that when iterating through x and y coordinates it is always opposite. X should be columns and y should be rows.

Comment: `range` also works, but adding the `-1` at the end removes the last `column` item and the entire last `row`. `xrange` is usually better in terms of performance. If you want a entire explanation of when to use `xrange` or `range`, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range

Comment: xrange has been replaced by range in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.nditer`.

```py
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'])
for x in it:
    print("{} {}".format(x, it.multi_index))
```

Reference: [Iterating Over Arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index)