# create a list with a variable part

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to create a list with a variable part :

```
mylist = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5']
```

I am trying :

```
i = range(1,5)
ii = [str(x) for x in i]
```

which works, and then I would like to do :

```
mylist = list('a' + x for x in ii)
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: The part you think is working is actually wrong, and the part you think doesn't work looks fine to me.

Comment: I am very sorry for the typo in the "range function". I'll be more focused next time. I get a  -  'list' object is not callable - error...

Comment: When you post to SO, don't type in your code, copy paste it.

Comment: You called one of your variables `list`. Stop doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranges are [half-open](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html) in Python so you must use `xrange(1,6)`, and although concatenation is fine (*between two strings*)  you could also use `str.format`. You can iterate over the numbers and append them to `a` in one go in a list comprehension with `xrange` ( see [`xrange` vs `range`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range)) such that you don't need to create two temporary lists in the process as you did:

```
>>> [str.format('a{0}', x) for x in xrange(1,6)]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
>>> ['a' + str(x) for x in xrange(1,6)]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```