# Why is xrange() faster than range()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

I timed both `range()` and `xrange()` expecting `range()` to be faster. But I got surprising results.

```
$ python -m timeit 'for i in range(1000000):' ' pass'
10 loops, best of 3: 39.9 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'for i in xrange(1000000):' ' pass'
10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 msec per loop
```

If I'm not mistaken, `range()` stores the whole list in memory while `xrange()` lazily evaluates the list.

So shouldn't accessing elements from the already generated list be faster than lazily evaluating the list and getting required elements? I don't get it.

Comment: But to generate all of those elements you have to do the same calculation that `xrange` is doing. The list form of `range` is only more useful when you need that list afterwards, e.g. if you're iterating more than once - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/135041/3001761

Comment: Also *"shouldn't accessing elements from the already generated list be faster than lazily evaluating the list and getting required elements"* - that isn't what you're testing. If you want to test that, create the `range` list beforehand and pass it in (not sure how you do `setup` on the command line with `timeit`, but...)

Comment: Pasting this question's exact title into a Google search yields several useful results. In the future, please try that before asking a new question.

Comment: per: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Use_xrange_instead_of_range

Much of the difference is the implementation in C instead of Python but the xrange function evaluates a range without creating a list of objects for each value in the range. Note also, this only applies to python 2, not python 3 as range in py3 is the same as xrange in py2 and there is no xrange in py3. Some say 'lazy, some say 'efficient' ;)