# Split a string at uppercase letters

Tags: python, regex, string

What is the [pythonic](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) way to split a string before the occurrences of a given set of characters?

For example, I want to split 
`'TheLongAndWindingRoad'`
at any occurrence of an uppercase letter (possibly except the first), and obtain
`['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']`.

Edit: It should also split single occurrences, i.e. 
from `'ABC'` I'd like to obtain
`['A', 'B', 'C']`.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to [split on a zero-width match](http://bugs.python.org/issue3262) in Python. But you can use `re.findall` instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'TheLongAndWindingRoad')
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'ABC')
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Beware that this will drop any characters before the first capital character. 'theLongAndWindingRoad' would result in ['Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']

Comment: @MarcSchulder: If you need that case, just use `'[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*'` as the regex.

Comment: It is possible to do te same without upercase ?

Comment: In order to split lower camel case words `print(re.findall('^[a-z]+|[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'theLongAndWindingRoad'))`

Comment: 'ThatLeadsToYourDooooor' <3

Comment: It is possible to split on a zero width match from 3.7

Comment: Is there a solution with ignores abbreviations i.e. where all the letters are Upper case Eg: ABCDE

Answer (score 51):

Here is an alternative regex solution.  The problem can be reprased as "how do I insert a space before each uppercase letter, before doing the split":

```
>>> s = "TheLongAndWindingRoad ABC A123B45"
>>> re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", s).split()
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A123', 'B45']
```

This has the advantage of preserving all non-whitespace characters, which most other solutions do not.

Comment: Can you please explain why does the space before \1 work? Is it because of the split method or is it anything related to regex?

Comment: split delimiter defaults to any whitespace string

Comment: @Lax_Sam the regex substitution just adds a space before any capital letter, and split() picks it up

Comment: I am always inspired when an intractable problem transforms into a no-brainer when rephrased.

Answer (score 32):

Use a lookahead and a lookbehind:

In Python 3.7, you can do this:

```
re.split('(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])', 'TheLongAndWindingRoad')
```

And it yields:

```
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

You need the look-behind to avoid an empty string at the beginning.

Comment: It will yield an empty string. re.split('(?=[A-Z])', 'ABC') get  ['', 'A', 'B', 'C']

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you're right.  I've updated my answer to avoid that.

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', 'TheLongAndWindingRoad')
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']

>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', 'SplitAString')
['Split', 'A', 'String']

>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', 'ABC')
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

If you want `"It'sATest"` to split to `["It's", 'A', 'Test']` change the rexeg to `"[A-Z][a-z']*"`

Comment: +1: For first to get ABC working. I've also updated my answer now.

Comment: >>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', "It's about 70% of the Economy") ----->
['It', 'Economy']

Comment: @ChristopheD. The OP doesn't say how to non-alpha characters should be treated.

Comment: true, but this current regex way also `drops` all regular (just plain alpha) words that do not start with an uppercase letter. I doubt that that was the intention of the OP.

Answer (score 16):

A variation on @ChristopheD 's solution

```
s = 'TheLongAndWindingRoad'

pos = [i for i,e in enumerate(s+'A') if e.isupper()]
parts = [s[pos[j]:pos[j+1]] for j in xrange(len(pos)-1)]

print parts
```

Comment: Nice one - this works with non-Latin characters too. The regex solutions shown here do not.

Comment: this also returns a list which was what I needed!

Comment: Note that it should be `range` instead of `xrange`.

Comment: I think `xrange` is fine, @raspiduino, not because I tested it in Python 2 but because it works in Python 3 with `range`, which is the same as `xrange`, apparently. There's no `xrange` in Python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 15):

I think that a better answer *might* be to split the string up into words that do not end in a capital.  This would handle the case where the string doesn't start with a capital letter.

```
 re.findall('.[^A-Z]*', 'aboutTheLongAndWindingRoad')
```

example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.[^A-Z]*', 'aboutTheLongAndWindingRoadABC')
['about', 'The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 8):

Pythonic way could be:

```
"".join([(" "+i if i.isupper() else i) for i in 'TheLongAndWindingRoad']).strip().split()
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

Works good for Unicode, avoiding re/re2.

```
"".join([(" "+i if i.isupper() else i) for i in 'СуперМаркетыПродажаКлиент']).strip().split()
['Супер', 'Маркеты', 'Продажа', 'Клиент']
```

Comment: Great way to do it without regex

Comment: Almost feels like it violates some of the python zen, though

Comment: I prefer this because there's no regex. Don't like the idea of loading a library and doing all that parsing when you just need to find the upper case letters. But there's no need to construct a list in between. This is more "Pythonic": `"".join(" " + c if c.isupper() else c for c in s).strip()` I can't see any violations here @rearThing. I'd be interested to know what you don't feel good about. It uses a generator expression after all: https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/ It looks better after you get rid of the unnecessary brackets and parentheses.

Answer (score 7):

```
import re
filter(None, re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", "TheLongAndWindingRoad"))
```

or

```
[s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", "TheLongAndWindingRoad") if s]
```

Comment: The filter is totally unnecessary and buys you nothing over a direct regex split with capture group: `[s for s in re.compile(r"([A-Z][^A-Z]*)").split( "TheLongAndWindingRoad") if s]` giving `['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']`

Comment: @smci: This usage of `filter` is the same as the list comprehension with a condition. Do you have anything against it?

Comment: I know it can be replaced with a list comprehension with a condition, because I just posted that code, then you copied it.

Here are three reasons the list comprehension is preferable:

a) *Legible idiom:* list comprehensions are a more Pythonic idiom and read clearer left-to-right than `filter(lambdaconditionfunc, ...)`
b) in Python 3, `filter()` returns an iterator. So they will not be totally equivalent.
c) I expect `filter()` is slower too

Answer (score 5):

```
src = 'TheLongAndWindingRoad'
glue = ' '

result = ''.join(glue + x if x.isupper() else x for x in src).strip(glue).split(glue)
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm forgot last step

Comment: Seems concise, pythonic and self-explanatory, to me.

Answer (score 5):

Another without regex and the ability to keep contiguous uppercase if wanted

```
def split_on_uppercase(s, keep_contiguous=False):
    """

    Args:
        s (str): string
        keep_contiguous (bool): flag to indicate we want to 
                                keep contiguous uppercase chars together

    Returns:

    """

    string_length = len(s)
    is_lower_around = (lambda: s[i-1].islower() or 
                       string_length > (i + 1) and s[i + 1].islower())

    start = 0
    parts = []
    for i in range(1, string_length):
        if s[i].isupper() and (not keep_contiguous or is_lower_around()):
            parts.append(s[start: i])
            start = i
    parts.append(s[start:])

    return parts

>>> split_on_uppercase('theLongWindingRoad')
['the', 'Long', 'Winding', 'Road']
>>> split_on_uppercase('TheLongWindingRoad')
['The', 'Long', 'Winding', 'Road']
>>> split_on_uppercase('TheLongWINDINGRoadT', True)
['The', 'Long', 'WINDING', 'Road', 'T']
>>> split_on_uppercase('ABC')
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> split_on_uppercase('ABCD', True)
['ABCD']
>>> split_on_uppercase('')
['']
>>> split_on_uppercase('hello world')
['hello world']
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution (if you dislike explicit regexes):

```
s = 'TheLongAndWindingRoad'

pos = [i for i,e in enumerate(s) if e.isupper()]

parts = []
for j in xrange(len(pos)):
    try:
        parts.append(s[pos[j]:pos[j+1]])
    except IndexError:
        parts.append(s[pos[j]:])

print parts
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace every uppercase letter 'L' in the given with an empty space plus that letter " L". We can do this using list comprehension or we can define a function to do it as follows.

```
s = 'TheLongANDWindingRoad ABC A123B45'
''.join([char if (char.islower() or not char.isalpha()) else ' '+char for char in list(s)]).strip().split()
>>> ['The', 'Long', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'Winding', 'Road', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A123', 'B45']
```

If you choose to go by a function, here is how.

```
def splitAtUpperCase(text):
    result = ""
    for char in text:
        if char.isupper():
            result += " " + char
        else:
            result += char
    return result.split()
```

In the case of the given example:

```
print(splitAtUpperCase('TheLongAndWindingRoad')) 
>>>['The', 'Long', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

But most of the time that we are splitting a sentence at upper case letters, it is usually the case that we want to maintain abbreviations that are typically a continuous stream of uppercase letters. The code below would help.

```
def splitAtUpperCase(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1)[::-1]:
        if s[i].isupper() and s[i+1].islower():
            s = s[:i]+' '+s[i:]
        if s[i].isupper() and s[i-1].islower():
            s = s[:i]+' '+s[i:]
    return s.split()

splitAtUpperCase('TheLongANDWindingRoad')

>>> ['The', 'Long', 'AND', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MarkByers I do not know why someone down voted my answer but I would love you to take a look at it for me. I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def solution(s):
   
    st = ''
    for c in s:
        if c == c.upper():
            st += ' '   
        st += c    
       
    return st
```

Comment: This will not split into lists like the question asks for.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for splitting on capitalized letters - keeps capitalized words

```
text = 'theLongAndWindingRoad ABC'
result = re.sub('(?<=.)(?=[A-Z][a-z])', r" ", text).split()
print(result)
#['the', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road', 'ABC']
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, the desired result was a list of strings, not a string with spaces inserted.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way without using regex or enumerate:

```
word = 'TheLongAndWindingRoad'
list = [x for x in word]

for char in list:
    if char != list[0] and char.isupper():
        list[list.index(char)] = ' ' + char

fin_list = ''.join(list).split(' ')
```

I think it is clearer and simpler without chaining too many methods or using a long list comprehension that can be difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the [`more_itertools.split_before`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.split_before) tool.

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = "TheLongAndWindingRoad"
[ "".join(i) for i in mit.split_before(iterable, pred=lambda s: s.isupper())]
# ['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

> It should also split single occurrences, i.e. from `'ABC'` I'd like to obtain `['A', 'B', 'C']`.

```
iterable = "ABC"
[ "".join(i) for i in mit.split_before(iterable, pred=lambda s: s.isupper())]
# ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party package with 60+ useful tools including implementations for all of the original [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which obviates their manual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You might also wanna do it this way

```
def camelcase(s):
    
    words = []
    
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper():
            words.append(':'+char)
        else:
            words.append(char)
    words = ((''.join(words)).split(':'))
    
    return len(words)
```

This will output as follows

```
s = 'oneTwoThree'
print(camecase(s)
//['one', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using list

```
def split_by_upper(x): 
i = 0       
lis = list(x)
while True:
    if i == len(lis)-1:
        if lis[i].isupper():
            lis.insert(i,",")
        break
    if lis[i].isupper() and i != 0:
        lis.insert(i,",")
        i+=1
    i+=1
return "".join(lis).split(",")
```

OUTPUT:

```
data = "TheLongAndWindingRoad"
print(split_by_upper(data))`
>> ['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

Comment: very bad code. very very long for no reason. It's like coding in the early 2000 in C

Answer (score 1):

Little late in the party, but:

```py
In [1]: camel = "CamelCaseConfig"
In [2]: parts = "".join([
    f"|{c}" if c.isupper() else c
    for c in camel
]).lstrip("|").split("|")
In [3]: screaming_snake = "_".join([
    part.upper()
    for part in parts
])
In [4]: screaming_snake
Out[4]: 'CAMEL_CASE_CONFIG'
```

part of my answer is based on other people answer from here

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```py
def split_string_after_upper_case(word):

    word_lst = [x for x in word]
    index = 0
    for char in word[1:]:
        index += 1
        if char.isupper():
            word_lst.insert(index, ' ')
            index += 1
    return ''.join(word_lst).split(" ")

k = split_string_after_upper_case('TheLongAndWindingRoad')
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way using **`enumerate`** and **`isupper()`**

**Code:**

```
strs = 'TheLongAndWindingRoad'
ind =0
count =0
new_lst=[]
for index, val in enumerate(strs[1:],1):
    if val.isupper():
        new_lst.append(strs[ind:index])
        ind=index
if ind<len(strs):
    new_lst.append(strs[ind:])
print new_lst
```

**Output:**

```
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what came to mind when I read the post. Different from other posts.

```
strs = 'TheLongAndWindingRoad'

# grab index of uppercase letters in strs
start_idx = [i for i,j in enumerate(strs) if j.isupper()]

# create empty list
strs_list = []

# initiate counter
cnt = 1

for pos in start_idx:
    start_pos = pos

    # use counter to grab next positional element and overlook IndexeError
    try:
        end_pos = start_idx[cnt]
    except IndexError:
        continue

    # append to empty list
    strs_list.append(strs[start_pos:end_pos])

    cnt += 1
```