# How to split strings based on capitalization?

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Split a string at uppercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/python-split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters)

I'm trying to figure out how to change `TwoWords` into `Two Words` and I can't think of a way to do it. I need to split based on where it's capitalized, that will always be a new word. Does anyone have any suggestions?

In python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this:

```
import re
words = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', 'TheWords')
```

Comment: This regexp won't work for non-ASCII letters.

Comment: @Jacek Konieczny - Since Python doesn't let you match based on unicode character properties, you either have to limit yourself to ASCII, or manually include characters and character ranges from languages you want to support. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]*","TwoWordsAATest")

re.findall("[A-Z][^A-Z]*","TwoWordsAATest")
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html