# How to split uppercase letters within a string?

Tags: python

```
s = "HiMyNameIsBob"

letters = ("A","B", "C", "D"...)

for char in s:
    if s.find(letters) is True:
```

I want the result to be

```
"Hi My Name Is Bob"
```

I want to avoid using the regex method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string at uppercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters)

Comment: If I'm not wrong this question is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters but that question is better phrased and has more and better answers. I vote to close but I wish we could delete.

Answer (score 10):

I might rely on the lexicographical ordering of strings here:

```
''.join( ' '+x if 'A' <= x <= 'Z' else x for x in s )
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = "HiMyNameIsBob"
>>> ''.join( ' '+x if 'A' <= x <= 'Z' else x for x in s )
' Hi My Name Is Bob'
```

If you don't want the leading space, you can always `.strip()` the result.

A slightly nicer way to check if the character is upper-case is by using the `isupper()` function (Thanks to Aesthete and wim for pointing this out):

```
>>> ''.join( ' '+x if x.isupper() else x for x in s )
' Hi My Name Is Bob'
```

Comment: +1, although I think `str.islower()` is much nicer option here.

Comment: @Aesthete -- That is nicer.  It's nicer even than my edit where I used `set(string.ascii_lowercase)`.  I didn't know about `str.islower` before this :)

Comment: Add a `.strip()` and you're golden!

Comment: how would i use str.lower() cuz it only returns true or false

Comment: I would prefer `x.isupper()` instead of `ord(x) >= 97`.  `islower()` would pad things like digits aswell.

Comment: @wim -- Yeah, `islower()` is better as pointed out by Aesthete -- I didn't know of the existence of that function before now.  Anyway, I have a second version which covers that.

Comment: @wim -- Isn't that what it's supposed to give?  If you're worried about the leading space, I already mentioned that it could be stripped off using `.strip()`.

Comment: Yes sorry.  I still think using `isupper` is preferable to `islower` here though, because characters such as '.' will fall into the wrong side of the conditional.

Comment: @wim -- Ahh, I see your point now.  I agree.  edited accordingly.

Comment: You could also use `"A" <= x <= "Z"` instead of `ord`. But `isupper()` is nicer anyway

Comment: @gnibbler -- once again proving that I wasn't really thinking when I started to answer this question :) -- I've finally removed `ord` all together from the solution (It's sometimes hard to let go of what you once thought clever -- even long after you realize it is a pretty dumb way to do it)

Answer (score 2):

You want [str.isupper()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

```
>>> s = "HiMyNameIsBob"
>>> t = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isupper())
>>> print t
HMNIB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

s = "HiMyNameIsBob"

letters = ("A","B", "C", "D"...)

for char in s:
    if s.find(letters):
        sys.stdout.write(' ')
    sys.stdout.write(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.sub('([A-Z])',' \g<1>', "HiMyNameIsBob").strip()
'Hi My Name Is Bob'
```

Comment: OP said to avdoid using regex