# how to split up an item in a line according to multiple factors (python)

Tags: python

I have a line in a file:

`['18G01G03G06G09G11G12G17G19G23G31G32R01']`

I need to split it up so that it results in:

`['18', 'G01', 'G03', 'G06', 'G09', 'G11', 'G12', 'G17', 'G19', 'G23', 'G31', 'G32', 'R01']`

I cant find a way on stackoverflow which explains this although i'm probs wrong.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like you might be looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/python-split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters

Answer (score 4):

You may use `re.findall`

```
import re
s = ['18G01G03G06G09G11G12G17G19G23G31G32R01']
re.findall(r'[A-Z]?\d+', s[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, I hadn't come across re.findall- relatively new to python :)

Comment: There's also `R` to split on.

Comment: Why not `r'[GR]?\d+'`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am sorry! I missed the `R`!

Answer (score 0):

Without using `regex` you could do it logically.

**Code:**

```
lst = ['18G01G03G06G09G11G12G17G19G23G31G32R01']
ind =0
count =0
new_lst=[]
for index, val in enumerate(lst[0]):
    if val.isalpha():
        new_lst.append(lst[0][ind:index])
        ind=index

if ind<len(lst[0]):
    new_lst.append(lst[0][ind:])
print new_lst
```

**Output:**

```
['18', 'G01', 'G03', 'G06', 'G09', 'G11', 'G12', 'G17', 'G19', 'G23', 'G31', 'G32', 'R01']
```