# Split a string into segments in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to split a molecule as a string into it's individual atom components. Each atom starts at a capital letter and ends at the last number.

For example, `'SO4'` would become `['S', 'O4']`.

And `'C6H12O6'` would become `['C6', 'H12', 'O6']`.

Pretty sure I need to use the regex module. This answer is close to what I'm looking for: [Split a string at uppercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/python-split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters)

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with the pattern:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*
```

- `[A-Z]` matches any uppercase character
- `[a-z]?` matches zero or one lowercase character
- `\d*` matches zero or more digits

Based on your example this should work, although you should look out for any specific library for this purpose.

**Example:**

```
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]?\d*', 'C6H12O6')
['C6', 'H12', 'O6']

>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]?\d*', 'SO4')
['S', 'O4']

>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]?\d*', 'HCl')
['H', 'Cl']
```

Comment: Perfect answer thanks! What about breaking up the individual components to their atom and number? So ['H12'] will become ['H', 12] and ['Ca2'] will become ['Ca', 2].