# Python - How to split array of strings at uppercase letters?

Tags: python, regex, string

**Input :** `['TotalAmt', 'ProgramServicesAmt', 'Desc']`

**Expected Output** : `['Total Amt', 'Program Services Amt', 'Desc']`

I am using :

```
>>> import re
>>> data = ['TotalAmt', 'ProgramServicesAmt', 'Desc']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', data)
```

Edit : 
**Error :**

```
expected string or buffer

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8002/data?ein=132618801
Django Version:     1.11.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

expected string or buffer
```

**Edit 2:** Use this also, but same error exist

```
re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", ['TotalAmt', 'ProgramServicesAmt', 'Desc']).split()
```

Comment: `re.findall()` accepts string not list.

Comment: @Kasramvd what is way to do for list ?

Comment: The error you get (which you didn't include in your question) tells you the problem.

Comment: You need to loop over the items and apply your regex on each element separately. You can use `re.sub()` for this purpose.

Comment: please check edit @Kasramvd

Comment: There are multiple answers to the core problem of splitting strings on upper case letters here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookarounds and a list comprehension:

```
import re

strings = ['TotalAmt', 'ProgramServicesAmt', 'Desc']

rx = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])')

nstrings = [rx.sub(' ', string) for string in strings]
print(nstrings)
# ['Total Amt', 'Program Services Amt', 'Desc']
```

Here, the expression `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` ensures there's a lowercase letter behind and an UPPERCASE letter ahead. This position is replaced by a space and put in a comprehension.

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lalpkQ/1).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `TypeError` because you are trying to apply [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) on a `list`. You have to get the `string` from the `list` and use that in your [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
>>> for s in l: 
        print(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*',s)) 
=>   
   ['Total', 'Amt']
   ['Program', 'Services', 'Amt']
   ['Desc']
```

Or a single liner `list comprehension` :

```
>>> [re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s) for s in l]
=> [['Total', 'Amt'], ['Program', 'Services', 'Amt'], ['Desc']]

#required format
>>> [' '.join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)) for s in l]
=> ['Total Amt', 'Program Services Amt', 'Desc']
```

#driver values:

```
IN : l = ['TotalAmt', 'ProgramServicesAmt', 'Desc']
```

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing to do is to simply insert a space before a capital letter. For example:

```
>>> re.sub('(?=[A-Z])', ' ', data[0])
' Total Amt'
```

However notice that a space will be inserted at the beginning. For that you can just strip the string ...

```
>>> re.sub('(?=[A-Z])', ' ', data[0]).strip()
'Total Amt'
```

The `?=` does a "non capturing version" of the match and hence this is possible ...

For applying the above scheme to all data, use list comprehension like everyone else ...

```
>>> [re.sub('(?=[A-Z])', ' ', d).strip() for d in data]
['Total Amt', 'Program Services Amt', 'Desc']
```

The advantage of this is that you will not have to check whether the return value is a `None` or not. This checking sometimes gets annoying when we use regex ...

```
>>> re.sub('(?=[A-Z])', ' ', 'dljlksdjf').strip()
'dljlksdjf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
data = ['TotalAmt', 'ProgramServicesAmt', 'Desc']
output=[]
for i in data:
    output.append(" ".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', i)))

print output
```

Output will be

```
['Total Amt', 'Program Services Amt', 'Desc']
```