# Split string at capital letter but only if no whitespace

Tags: python, string, split, whitespace

**Set-up**

I've got a string of names which need to be separated into a list.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters), I have,

```
string = 'KreuzbergLichtenbergNeuköllnPrenzlauer Berg'
re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', string)
```

where the last line gives me,

```
['Kreuzberg', 'Lichtenberg', 'Neuk', 'Prenzlauer', 'Berg']
```

---

**Problems**

**1) Whitespace is ignored**

'Prenzlauer Berg' is actually 1 name but the code splits according to the 'split-at-capital-letter' rule.

What is the command ensuring it to **not** split at a capital letter if preceding character is a whitespace?

**2) Special characters not handled well**

The code used cannot handle `'ö'`. How do I include such 'German' characters?

I.e. I want to obtain,

```
['Kreuzberg', 'Lichtenberg', 'Neukölln', 'Prenzlauer Berg']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use positive and negative lookbehind and just list the Umlauts explicitly:

```
>>> string = 'KreuzbergLichtenbergNeuköllnPrenzlauer Berg'
>>> re.findall('(?<!\s)[A-ZÄÖÜ](?:[a-zäöüß\s]|(?<=\s)[A-ZÄÖÜ])*', string)
['Kreuzberg', 'Lichtenberg', 'Neukölln', 'Prenzlauer Berg']
```

`(?<!\s)...`: matches `...` that is not preceded by `\s`

`(?<=\s)...`: matches `...` that is preceded by `\s`

`(?:...)`: non-capturing group so as to not mess with the findall results

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
string="KreuzbergLichtenbergNeuköllnPrenzlauer Berg"
pattern="[A-Z][a-ü]+\s[A-Z][a-ü]+|[A-Z][a-ü]+"
re.findall(pattern, string)
#>>>['Kreuzberg', 'Lichtenberg', 'Neukölln', 'Prenzlauer Berg']
```