# How to split a string at uppercase letters from a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I want to separate all characters that start with uppercase characters in this dataframe column.

```
Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz']
0          ClinicadeOlhosSaoPauloLtda-Me
1        PatriciaAparecidaMendesFerreira
2        CarraroHoldingParticipaçõesLtda
3               IsadoraCentofantiFonseca
4       Petruso&PetrusoSupermercadosLtda
....
Name: TesteNomeJuiz, Length: 1510, dtype: object
```

**And i already used a function that allows me to do that it seems not to work**

```
def camel_case_split(identifier):
matches = finditer('.+?(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|$)', identifier)
return [m.group(0) for m in matches]
```

---

```
Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'].astype('str')
splitted = re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'])).split
```

---

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-00cc9d0b832f> in <module>
1 Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'].astype('str')
--> 2 splitted = re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', 
Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'])).split
F:\Anaconda\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
208     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
209     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 210     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
211 
212 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**And i also tried to  call The info() function but doesn't work**

```
Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'].info()
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-403d0ae3c1ac> in <module>
--> 1 Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'].info()
F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5273                 return self[name]
->5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
5275 
5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'info'
```

Comment: Can you provide an expected output of your sample as well?

Comment: Try `Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'].str.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string at uppercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call .info() on a pandas.DataFrame, not on a pandas.Series.

Assuming Unicainstancia_DF is a DataFrame, you could call: `Unicainstancia_DF.info()`, but not `Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz'].info()`

You're using a series/column selector when you use `Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz']` --
you've selected a column (or 'Series') from a DataFrame and are about to do something with it.

What, precisely, you want to do with that Series isn't clear to me from your example. If you want to split on A-Z, then you could do something like this:

```py
import re

print([re.split(r'[A-Z]', x) for x in Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz']]
```

But as Chris suggests, if you clarify your expected output and where you're wanting to store the splits I can be more specific. It seems doubtful that you actually want to split on A-Z -- more likely is that you want to split on the boundary between A-Z and any other character. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks for the help, well basically i want my output this way:

**Clinicade Olhos Sao Paulo Ltda- Me**
**Patricia Aparecida Mendes Ferreira**
**Carraro Holding Participações Ltda**

it occurs when i have a upper letter in my string. I don`t know if i was clear but i just want to split Upper Characters in this collumn. I have already used your solution but no successful.
`print([re.split(r'[A-Z]', x) for x in Unicainstancia_DF['TesteNomeJuiz']]`
`SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`