# Include text that you have split on in re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that is

```
mystring = 'Aston VillaLiverpoolMan City'
```

My goal is to get the output below

```
"Aston Villa", "Liverpool", "Man City".
```

ie to spilt on the capital letter when it isnt preceded by a space

I am getting close with re.findall but it is not providing the output that I want

```
import re 
    
myString = 'Aston VillaLiverpoolMan City'
result = re.findall("(?<!\s)[A-Z][a-z]*",myString)
print(result)
```

This produces

```
"Aston", "Liverpool", "Man"
```

(missing the Villa at the end of Aston and the City at the end of Man)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris is it doesn't help. That question is for splitting on the capital letter only not also when there isn't a space before it (unless i have missed something)

Comment: As OP mentioned in his comment. Its not actually an exact duplicate. OP is looking for a solution to skip Capital letter followed by Space.

Comment: Try this and stitching the answer together is easy:  
result = re.split("(\B[A-Z])",myString)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters) posted by @Chris does answer your query, except it needed a little alteration.

```
s = 'Aston VillaLiverpoolMan City'
pos = [i for i,e in enumerate(s+'A') if e.isupper() and s[i-1]!=" "]
parts = [s[pos[j]:pos[j+1]] for j in range(len(pos)-1)]
print (parts)
```

results in

```
['Aston Villa', 'Liverpool', 'Man City']
```

Credit goes to @pwdyson.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will also have another look at the link

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @vanisk is perfect.

You can also try

```
mystring = 'Aston VillaLiverpoolMan City'
s = list(mystring)
for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if ord(s[i]) in range(65, 91):
        if s[i-1]!=' ':
            s[i]='\n'+s[i]

splitstring = ''.join(s).split('\n')
print(splitstring)
```

This too gives

```
['Aston Villa', 'Liverpool', 'Man City']
```