# How would I divide a string after a specific character in Python

Tags: python, string, split

EDIT: Thank you for so many responses and apologies for ambiguous question, and poorly constructed example. I didn't mean to split the word by the uppercase character. I literally mean to split the string after a specific character like 'X', 'r', or 'o'.

I'm trying to split a long string of repeating words like "FooXXBarBazXBar ..." into a list of words ['Fo', 'o', 'X', 'X', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'X', 'Bar' ...].

In c I would create a new array of characters and copy characters one by one, inserting a delimiter after a specific character, to later split on the delimiter like this:

```
{
    char *newString = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
    int offset=0;

    //copy characters from old string to the new one, inserting ';' after a specific character

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(string); i < n; i++)
    {
        newString[i+offset] = string[i];
        if ((string[i] == 'o') || (string[i] == 'r') || (string[i] == 'z') || (string[i] == 'X'))
        {
            offset += 1;
            newString[i+offset] = ';';
        }
    }

    //split the string into an array of strings on the delimiter ';'
    split_string(newString);
}
```

I'm still a beginner, so it's probably also not that great, but it works.

I'm trying to work around this in python, but cannot come up with a good approach.

How would you go about it? Thanks :)

Comment: I think you must better specify the problem on how the split will work, why for instance is `Foo` split out and not `FooX` or `FooXX` for that matter. I think you want to split out repeating patterns of letters (starting with the longest patterns), So for `Foo` to be split out somewhere in the string there should be another `Foo` pattern, etc.

Comment: Also why you use the key word `Python` while your code snippet is in `C`?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen maybe a result word must end with `[aeiou]`?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. My snippet is in C, because there I know how to implement it. I used the Python keyword, because I'm looking for the solution of this problem in Python. I made a mistake in my example showing input "Foo" and output ["Foo"]. In what I'm looking for it would give an output of ["Fo", "o"] I want to define in my code a specific character and split the string after that character.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, and what you want to do is to split each word on an uppercase letter ("HelloWorldPython" -> ["Hello", "World", "Python"]

I would use regex:

```py
import re
text = "FooXXBarBazXBar"
re.findall(r'[A-Z][^A-Z]*', text) # Uppercase letter followed by 0 or more non-uppercased character
['Foo', 'X', 'X', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'X', 'Bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quesiton is kind of ambiguous. It's not clear at which characters you wanna split the string but if these are ['o','r','X','z'] then the following code will do:

```
string = input()
word = ''
words_list = []
for char in string: # iterate through the string
    word += char # add the character to the word
    if(char in ['o','r','X','z']): # check if the character at current iteration is one of the characters in the list
        words_list.append(word) # add the word formed by now to the list
        word = '' # re-initialize the word variable to an empty string so as to start the next word
print(words_list)
```

This would output:

```
['Fo', 'o', 'X', 'X', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'X', 'Bar', 'xxX']
```

###### Warning: As you have specified 'o' as a splitting cahracter it will never give you 'Foo' in order to get 'Foo' instead of 'Fo' in the list you will have to add more code within the loop.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! I made a mistake in my example choosing word "foo" and not noticing it has two 'o's in it 

Comment: Welcome ! @Nishijama there's nothing wrong with mistakes infact these are beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a string into parts starting with an uppercase.
like splitting **"ThisIsALineAsAnExample"** to **['This','Is','A','Line','As','An','Example']**

if this is what you want to do then this may help

```
i=0
j=1
final=[]
s="ThisIsALineAsAnExample"
while(i<len(s)):
    if(s[i].isupper()):
        new_str=s[i]
        j=i+1
        while(j<len(s) and s[j].islower()):
            new_str=new_str+s[j]
            j=j+1
        print(new_str)
    i=j
    final.append(new_str)

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

The example input and the ouput suggests that you want to split every word that starts with an uppercase letter.

For Python, a solution with this approach [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters).

If you want to apply it to your solution in C too,you can check if a char is uppercase by:

```
if(string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') {
    offset += 1;
    newString[i+offset] = ';';
}
```