# Python - Initializing Multiple Lists/Line

Tags: python, list, initialization

This is terribly ugly:

```
psData = []
nsData = []
msData = []
ckData = []
mAData = []
RData = []
pData = []
```

Is there a way to declare these variables on a single line?

Comment: I don't think it's ugly, especially if you do psData = [] # Some comment explaining what's in there

Comment: Ugliness or not, beware with those names so similar one to each other: psData and pdata, mAData and msData...

Comment: -1: Don't replace this with some "code golf" construction that uses the minimum number of keystrokes.  This is nice.  Anything more terse will baffle and frustrate folks who want to maintain this program.  Indeed, anything more obscure than this will likely get rewritten to this.

Comment: It shouldn't be baffling if the coder includes a comment to explain what the line of code does, like # initialize list variables

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist = ([] for i in range(5))
```

The downside of above approach is, you need to count the number of names on the left of `=` and have exactly the same number of empty lists (e.g. via the `range` call, or more explicitly) on the right hand 
side.

The main thing is, **don't** use something like

```
alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist = [[]] * 5
```

nor

```
alist = blist = clist = dlist = elist = []
```

which would make all names refer to the **same** empty list!

Comment: Great answer, I was trying to do the C style of `alist, blist, clist = []` and failing untill I found this

Comment: Does it apply to dictionaries too?

Comment: Yes, it does apply to dictionaries too.  That's what I was looking for until I came across this question and answer.

Answer (score 34):

```
psData,nsData,msData,ckData,mAData,RData,pData = [],[],[],[],[],[],[]
```

Comment: you can verify the lists do not share memory addresses with `print('my_list =', hex(id(my_list)))` - this solution is not slowed down by using `range`

Answer (score 12):

Depending on your needs, you could consider using a defaultdict with a list factory.
Something like:

```
my_lists = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

and then you can directly append to my_lists["psData"] and so on.
This is the relevant doc page: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 4):

A bit more efficient approach:

```
alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist = ([] for _ in xrange(5))
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `xrange()` is more optimal than `range()` in *Python2*.  <sup>([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x))</sup>
- The `i` variable was unusable so using `_` is better. <sup>([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47599668/3702377))</sup>
- `xrange()` is no longer in *Python3* — `range()` is the same with `xrange()`.

Comment: How can something be "more optimal" than something else? :)

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that, tidiness may come with consequences of performance. The range function call will slow down the init process slightly. Beware if you have some process that need to reinit the variable many time.

```
import time
def r_init():
    st=time.time()
    alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist = ([] for i in range(5))
    et=time.time()
    print("{:.15f}".format(et-st))

def p_init():
    st=time.time()
    alist=[];blist=[];clist=[];dlist=[];elist=[]
    et=time.time()
    print("{:.15f}".format(et-st))

for x in range(1,10):
    r_init()
    p_init()
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a class to initialize/store the data, it would take more lines, but could be easier to read, and more object oriented.

Like:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1=[]
        <etc.>
    def zeroize(self):
        self.var1=[]
        <etc.>
```

Then in main near the beginning:

```
data=Data()
```

Then in your loops or anywhere in main post declaration you can use the class.

```
data.var1.append(varN)
if(something):
    data.zeroize()
```

Comment: this is essentially just a dict, also - it does not solve the OP's question, nor is it simpler, the OP clearly wanted less code, and less hassle, this is not that. however, this is a different type of solution to the problem, that does merit something, but it can be done much better, also, you have used some strange names.

Answer (score -6):

Something along the lines of

```
alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist = ([],)*5
```

would appear to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: `alist.append("oops"); print(blist)`: `['oops']`.