# More elegant way of declaring multiple variables at the same time

Tags: python, variables, declaration

To declare multiple variables at the "same time" I would do:

```
a, b = True, False
```

But if I had to declare much more variables, it turns less and less elegant:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = True, True, True, True, True, False, True ,True , True, True
```

Is there a better / elegant / convenient way to do this?

This must be very basic, but if I do used a list or a tuple for storing the variables, how would I have to approach so that I would be helpful since:

```
aList = [a,b]
```

Is not valid, I would have to do:

```
a, b = True, True
```

Or what am I missing?

Comment: Use a list to store those values?  A dictionary?  A (named) tuple?

Comment: @Chris: I was getting there.  :)

Comment: @JeffM: maybe but I don't know how to do that it seems that they have to be defined in order to belong to a list (I may be wrong of course)

Comment: @Trufa: If you are going to be declaring that many variables to store values, that is already a sign you should be considering other storage alternatives IMHO.

Comment: @Jeff Agreed, along with the fact they're (very descriptively) named a-j. Consider using bitmasks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29

Comment: @JeffM: Until know I couldn't find a way around it but I know this it not ideal.

Comment: @user470379 - I kind of assumed that the names were just for the example code, and that Trufa isn't using those names in his real code.

Comment: @Jeff and @Chris I've edited my question since I don't understand how to use a list or tuple to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can do `a=b=True`

Comment: `a, b = (True,)*2`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As others have suggested, it's unlikely that using 10 different local variables with Boolean values is the best way to write your routine (especially if they really have one-letter names :)

Depending on what you're doing, it may make sense to use a dictionary instead.  For example, if you want to set up Boolean preset values for a set of one-letter flags, you could do this:

```
>>> flags = dict.fromkeys(["a", "b", "c"], True)
>>> flags.update(dict.fromkeys(["d", "e"], False))
>>> print flags
{'a': True, 'c': True, 'b': True, 'e': False, 'd': False}
```

---

If you prefer, you can also do it with a single assignment statement:

```
>>> flags = dict(dict.fromkeys(["a", "b", "c"], True),
...              **dict.fromkeys(["d", "e"], False))
>>> print flags
{'a': True, 'c': True, 'b': True, 'e': False, 'd': False}
```

The second parameter to `dict` isn't entirely designed for this: it's really meant to allow you to override individual elements of the dictionary using keyword arguments like `d=False`.  The code above blows up the result of the expression following `**` into a set of [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) which are passed to the called function.  This is certainly a reliable way to create dictionaries, and people seem to be at least accepting of this idiom, but I suspect that some may consider it Unpythonic.  `</disclaimer>`

---

Yet another approach, which is likely the most intuitive if you will be using this pattern frequently, is to define your data as a list of flag values (`True`, `False`) mapped to flag names (single-character strings).  You then transform this data definition into an inverted dictionary which maps flag names to flag values.  This can be done quite succinctly with a nested list comprehension, but here's a very readable implementation:

```
>>> def invert_dict(inverted_dict):
...     elements = inverted_dict.iteritems()
...     for flag_value, flag_names in elements:
...         for flag_name in flag_names:
...             yield flag_name, flag_value
... 
>>> flags = {True: ["a", "b", "c"], False: ["d", "e"]}
>>> flags = dict(invert_dict(flags))
>>> print flags
{'a': True, 'c': True, 'b': True, 'e': False, 'd': False}
```

The function `invert_dict` is a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators).  It *generates*, or *yields* — meaning that it *repeatedly returns values of* — key-value pairs.  Those key-value pairs are the inverse of the contents of the two elements of the initial `flags` dictionary.  They are fed into the `dict` constructor.  In this case the `dict` constructor works differently from above because it's being fed an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) rather than a dictionary as its argument.

---

Drawing on @Chris Lutz's comment: If you will really be using this for single-character values, you can actually do

```
>>> flags = {True: 'abc', False: 'de'}
>>> flags = dict(invert_dict(flags))
>>> print flags
{'a': True, 'c': True, 'b': True, 'e': False, 'd': False}
```

This works because Python strings are [*iterable*](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable), meaning that they can be moved through value by value.  In the case of a string, the values are the individual characters in the string.  So when they are being interpreted as iterables, as in this case where they are being used in a for loop, `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `'abc'` are effectively equivalent.  Another example would be when they are being passed to a function that takes an iterable, like [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple).

I personally wouldn't do this because it doesn't read intuitively: when I see a string, I expect it to be used as a single value rather than as a list.  So I look at the first line and think "Okay, so there's a True flag and a False flag."  So although it's a possibility, I don't think it's the way to go.  On the upside, it may help to explain the concepts of iterables and iterators more clearly.

---

Defining the function `invert_dict` such that it actually returns a dictionary is not a bad idea either; I mostly just didn't do that because it doesn't really help to explain how the routine works.

---

Apparently Python 2.7 has dictionary comprehensions, which would make for an extremely concise way to implement that function.  This is left as an exercise to the reader, since I don't have Python 2.7 installed :)

You can also combine some functions from the ever-versatile [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module.  As they say, [There's More Than One Way To Do It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).  Wait, the Python people don't say that.  Well, it's true anyway in some cases.  I would guess that Guido hath given unto us dictionary comprehensions so that there would be [One Obvious Way](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) to do this.

Comment: Note that `['a', 'b', 'c']` can be shortened to `list('abc')`, which inspires `def truth_values(trues, falses): d = dict.from_keys(list(trues), True); d.update(dict.from_keys(list(falses), False)); return d` used as `values = truth_values("abc", "de")`

Comment: Thank you very much this seems like a very comprehensive answer, I will give it good look through and experiment with what you prose, what you are saying, while it is probably true, it doesn't come natural to may so I will have to read a bit and play around until I fully get what you mean specially since dictionaries that is one of my weaknesses in python yet. Thank you very much, I'll be back :)

Comment: @Trufa: Enjoy.  There are probably a few interesting new concepts in here for you.  Generator functions are usually considered more advanced, so you might want to wait on that bit.  Then again, they might be really easy for you; it's partly that they're not as commonly understood as other topics because not a lot of popular languages have them.

Comment: @intuited I'm flabbergasted by your answer: you define another problem than the OP's one and you delight to do a long answer to this other problem. He doesn't want to associate strings and values in a dictionary, he wants to create objects with an identifier and a value for each one.

Comment: @eyquem: Long answers are bad? Physician, heal thyself!

Comment: @John Machin No, a long answer isn't automatically bad. I am simply puzzled by a long explanation concerning a problem that is not the problem asked by the OP. His "answer" is a good one, but for another question.

Comment: @eyquem: Perhaps the length of my question caused its first sentence to be obscured?  Also.. technically, when you assign to local variables in Python, you are actually creating objects which are stored in the dictionary which comprises the local namespace.  The `locals` function will actually return that dictionary.  However, it's considered poor form, and is not really reliable, to manipulate the locals dictionary directly.  So one of the advantages of using a dictionary rather than local variables is that you can use higher-level routines to define and manipulate those identifiers.

Comment: @intuited In your dictionaries, there are not identifiers, there are strings. Someone explained me, one time here on stackoverflow, that in fact the namespaces are not dictionaries; they are .. something I don't know the nature.. and it's when one wants to see into them that the data in namespaces are presented under the form of dictionaries. It seems to me it was Michael Foord who explained me that. So, going from identifiers to strings is changing the nature of the "problem"

Comment: @intuited I agree with you that , instead of using 10 identifiers, he could use a dictionary of ten items whose keys would be strings. OK . But it is INSTEAD, not equivalent. By the way, an instance of a class, or a list , or something else could be another solution too. There is no reason for a dictionary precisely. In fact, it's the question that is weird: he presents a delimited question that can't have sense outside a context and he doesn't give the context. I wonder why I take care of these kind of partial questions.

Comment: @eyquem: You may be right about the locals dictionary.. actually the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) explain that the dictionary is just "*representing* the local namespace".  But then, for example, [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) takes a dictionary parameter which determines local variables during the evaluation and holds them afterwards.  The similarity runs pretty deep: even in the C API, the function [PyEval_EvalCodeEx](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyEval_EvalCodeEx) takes as a parameter a dictionary of local variables.

Comment: @eyquem: I guess the point is really that both the set of local variables and the keys of a dictionary represent a *namespace*.  As you mention, without more information on the context of the question, we can't really say for sure what sort of namespace is most appropriate, but given that these variables are all Boolean it seems most likely that they should be grouped together.  In that case it's most sensible to store them in a dictionary and to profit from functions like `dict.fromkeys`.

Comment: Sometimes, people just want to get work done and not worry about whether is the 'best' way or not.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and it's patronising. See the answer below

Comment: This really is not the answer to the asked question. Better answers below.

Answer (score 262):

```
a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i, j = (True,)*9
f = False
```

Comment: @Imray Trailing comma notation `(d,)` creates a one-item tuple, which is a sequence type. [Sequence types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) support addition and multiplication, among other operations.

Comment: Elegant trick, but be aware of using this on mutable elements such as lists. For example `a, b, c = ([],)*3` does not create 3 list instances but makes `a`, `b` and `c` pointing to the same instance.

Comment: I wonder much my time I waste/spend trying to make my python code uber pythonic?

Comment: @Zac to correctly do so use `a, b, c = ([] for i in range(3))`. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line). For consistency, you could also use a variant of that for this answer, i.e., `a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j = (True for i in range(9))` `f=(False i in range(1))`.

Comment: This is an example as to why i love python, Only using it recently.. I wish is started earlier.. But web development does varying depending on the project.

Comment: I don't think that these all different variables than each other, rather it is just a copy of the other.If you will change any one of it, all will get changed by itself.

Answer (score 67):

Use a list/dictionary or define your own class to encapsulate the stuff you're defining, but if you need all those variables you can do:

```
a = b = c = d = e = g = h = i = j = True
f = False
```

Comment: vars will not be set to True & False only.

Comment: @N1.1: I could not understand what you meant by that.

Comment: @Trufa If they are set to True/False only, the suggested way is perfect, but what if variables are set to different things?

Comment: @N1.1: Ohh I get what you mean, thanks for the clarification! In this case, they are all bools but it's good to know. Thanks

Comment: For an explanation of why this is a dangerous pattern (albeit working example), read up on [Notorious B.I.G.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349356/134610)

Comment: It is a risky solution if you want to assign objects instead of literals (like True or False). You may not want to have many vars pointing/accessing the same object.

Comment: @duozmo it seems the summary is that it is safe for single variables, but the danger is when they are list. So reassigning a list entry in names that have been linked can dangerous (not intuitive). For example, `>>a=b=[1,2]` > `>>a[0]=3` > `>>print b` >  `[3,2]`. The value of `b[0]` has also changed since `>>a=b`. However this seems safe (intuitive): `>>a=b=2` > `>>a=3` > `>>print b` > `2`.

Comment: For the single variable case, reassignment breaks the linkage. This  can be seen with `>>print id(a)-id(b)` or `>>print a is b`

Comment: I don't think that these all different variables than each other, rather it is just a copy of the other.If you will change any one of it, all will get changed by itself.

Answer (score 11):

This is an elaboration on @[Jeff M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-m)'s and my comments.

When you do this:

```
a, b = c, d
```

It works with tuple packing and unpacking. You can separate the packing and unpacking steps:

```
_ = c, d
a, b = _
```

The first line creates a tuple called `_` which has two elements, the first with the value of `c` and the second with the value of `d`. The second line unpacks the `_` tuple into the variables `a` and `b`. This breaks down your one huge line:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True
```

Into two smaller lines:

```
_ = True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = _
```

It will give you the exact same result as the first line (including the same exception if you add values or variables to one part but forget to update the other). 
However, in this specific case, [yan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495332/more-elegant-way-of-declaring-multiple-variables-at-the-same-time/5495350#5495350) is perhaps the best.

If you have a list of values, you can still unpack them. You just have to convert it to a tuple first. For example, the following will assign a value between 0 and 9 to each of `a` through `j`, respectively:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = tuple(range(10))
```

EDIT: Neat trick to assign all of them as true except element 5 (variable `f`):

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = tuple(x != 5 for x in range(10))
```

Comment: I did not know the last one was possible, I will definitely give it a try, it is indeed a neat trick and it may come in handy!

Answer (score 5):

When people are suggesting "use a list or tuple or other data structure", what they're saying is that, when you have a lot of different values that you care about, naming them all separately as local variables may not be the best way to do things.

Instead, you may want to gather them together into a larger data structure that can be stored in a single local variable.

intuited showed how you might use a dictionary for this, and Chris Lutz showed how to use a tuple for temporary storage before unpacking into separate variables, but another option to consider is to use `collections.namedtuple` to bundle the values more permanently.

So you might do something like:

```
# Define the attributes of our named tuple
from collections import namedtuple
DataHolder = namedtuple("DataHolder", "a b c d e f g")

# Store our data
data = DataHolder(True, True, True, True, True, False, True)

# Retrieve our data
print(data)
print(data.a, data.f)
```

Real code would hopefully use more meaningful names than "DataHolder" and the letters of the alphabet, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will be checking this out as an option, the thing is that (**for this particular case**) it may not be useful to have and immutable structure. I will comment later on how this turned out, again many thanks!

Comment: You can do the same thing with an ordinary class - the definition of `DataHolder` just gets a little more verbose.

Answer (score 4):

What's the problem , in fact ?

If you really need or want 10 **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**, **e**, **f**, **g**, **h**, **i**, **j** , there will be no other possibility, at a time or another, to write **a** and write **b** and write **c**.....

If the values are all different, you will be obliged to write for exemple

```
a = 12
b= 'sun'
c = A() #(where A is a class)
d = range(1,102,5)
e = (line in filehandler if line.rstrip())
f = 0,12358
g = True
h = random.choice
i = re.compile('^(!=  ab).+?<span>')
j = [78,89,90,0]
```

that is to say defining the "variables" individually.

Or , using another writing, no need to use `_` :

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j =\
12,'sun',A(),range(1,102,5),\
(line for line in filehandler if line.rstrip()),\
0.12358,True,random.choice,\
re.compile('^(!=  ab).+?<span>'),[78,89,90,0]
```

or

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j =\
(12,'sun',A(),range(1,102,5),
 (line for line in filehandler if line.rstrip()),
 0.12358,True,random.choice,
 re.compile('^(!=  ab).+?<span>'),[78,89,90,0])
```

.

If some of them must have the same value, is the problem that it's too long to write

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = True, True, True, True, True, False, True ,True , True, True
```

?

Then you can write:

```
a=b=c=d=e=g=h=i=k=j=True
f = False
```

.

I don't understand what is exactly your problem. If you want to write a code, you're obliged to use the characters required by the writing of the instructions and definitions.  What else ?

I wonder if your question isn't the sign that you misunderstand something.

When one writes `a = 10` , **one don't create a variable** in the sense of "chunk of memory whose value can change". This instruction:

- either triggers the creation of an object of type `integer` and value 10 and the binding of a name 'a' with this object in the current namespace
- or re-assign the name 'a' in the namespace to the object **10** (because 'a' was precedently binded to another object)

I say that because I don't see the utility to define 10 identifiers a,b,c... pointing to False or True. If these values don't change during the execution, why 10 identifiers ? And if they change, why defining the identifiers first ?, they will be created when needed if not priorly defined

Your question appears weird to me

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're approaching your problem the wrong way to me.

Rewrite your code to use a tuple or write a class to store all of the data.

Comment: Thank you for you can you say that without even a glimpse of the code :) I do understand that this it not ideal, and I may have to reformat but your answer doesn't really solve the question. I do get your point though.

Comment: I can say that it sounds like that, yes. It is what it sounds like. Refactoring will likely solve your problem. Your problem is a style issue, not a functional one so it's hard to offer anything other than quite metadvice.

Answer (score 2):

Like *JavaScript* you can also use multiple statements on one line in python `a = 1; b = "Hello World"; c += 3`

Answer (score 1):

I like the top voted answer; however, it has problems with list as shown.

```
  >> a, b = ([0]*5,)*2
  >> print b
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  >> a[0] = 1
  >> print b
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is discussed in great details [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348815/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-value-list-behavior/16349356#16349356), but the gist is that `a` and `b` are the same object with `a is b` returning `True` (same for `id(a) == id(b)`). Therefore if you change an index, you are changing the index of both `a` and `b`, since they are linked. To solve this you can do [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line)

```
>> a, b = ([0]*5 for i in range(2))
>> print b
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>> a[0] = 1
>> print b
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

This can then be used as a variant of the top answer, which has the "desired" intuitive results

```
>> a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i = (True for i in range(9))
>> f = (False for i in range(1)) #to be pedantic
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would use YAML .

That is an elegant and professional standard for dealing with multiple parameters.
The values are loaded from a separate file.
You can see some info in this link:

https://keleshev.com/yaml-quick-introduction

But it is easier to Google it, as it is a standard, there are hundreds of info about it, you can find what best fits to your understanding. ;)

Best regards.

Comment: Hi Henrique, welcome to SO, thank  you for your answer! Please make sure to read up on [writing an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering your next question!