# Assign multiple variables Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell

Is there a way to assign the same value to multiple variables in Haskell?
e.g something like this:

```
h,f = 5
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there some other language you have in mind that can do this?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348815/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-value-list-behavior).

Comment: @ChrisMartin in Python you can do `h = f = 5`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin In R you can even do `f <- 5 -> h`

Answer (score 4):

```
Prelude> let [x, y] = replicate 2 5
Prelude> x
5
Prelude> y
5
Prelude>
```

You need `replicate` to "duplicate" a value. In this case, I duplicating 5 twice. `[x, y]` mean get `x` and `y` from a List. That list is `[5, 5]`. So, you got `x = 5` and `y = 5`.

Well, I never did such behavior in the real world Haskell but you get what you want.

**EDIT**: We could use `repeat` function and the feature of lazy evaluation in the Haskell. Thanks to [luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33796/luqui).

```
Prelude> let x:y:_ = repeat 5
Prelude> x
5
Prelude> y
5
Prelude>
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the possible pattern match error if you mismatch the length of the list with the number to replicate, use `repeat` instead:  `let x:y:_ = repeat 5`.  And I, too, have never seen this idiom in the wild, and suspect it to be rather futile for reasons @absolutezero mentions.

Comment: @luqui I forgot that I could use `repeat` and the feature of lazy evaluation. Thanks!