# why I get this error 'int' object is not iterable when I Initialize two variables at once

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a beginner of python and follow a book to practice.
In my book, the author uses this code

```
s, k = 0
```

but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I want to know what happened here.

Comment: `s, k = 0, 0` instead.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348815/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-value-list-behavior

Comment: Or just `s = k = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking to initialize two variables `s` and `k` using a single int object `0`, which of course is not iterable.

The corrrect syntax being:

```
s, k = 0, 0
```

**Where**

```
s, k = 0, 1
```

Would assign `s = 0` and `k = 1`

> Notice the each `int` object on the right being initialized to the
>   corresponding `var` on the left.

**OR**

```
s,k = [0 for _ in range(2)]

print(s)    # 0
print(k)    # 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = k = 0
```

OR

```
s, k = (0, 0)
```

depends on what u need

Answer (score 0):

Insted of:

```
s, k = 0
```

Use:

```
s, k = 0,0
```