# Initiate multiple variables with a value Python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, variable-assignment, python-3.7

I have working on JavaScript, C#, Java for so long. In these we can initiate multiple variables with same value;

```
var a, b, c = 0
```

**OR**

```
int a, b, c = 0
```

Trying to do the same in python but unable to do it. Tried many things like;

```
a = b = c = 0
```

its working with `int` but with `list`

[image]

but it creates reference to other variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Python all variables are objects, therefore references to one thing

Comment: Are you trying to apply this to mutable objects? In this exact case, it shouldn't matter that `a`, `b` and `c` all reference the same number since `0` is immutable.

Comment: @Petronella ,  Updated my question of what I am trying to

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to mutate value for each variable separately after declaring it

Comment: Because List is an object, a,b and c are references to the same address where this one list is stored. So you don't have 3 separate lists on 3 separate disk addresses with 3 references, each for a list.

Comment: See this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348815/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-value-list-behavior. It essentially explains that `int` is immutable; so in your case, 0 is 0 forever. `Lists` behave differently because they are mutable.

Comment: @Petronella, Yeah I get that but without creating reference to each other.

Comment: @gmdev `a,b,c = [],[],[]` is ok but we want to mimic `a,b,c = []`  of java and other programming languages without creating references

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you could get is to repeat the list via some means. Since Python unfortunately doesn't have an equivalent to Clojure's [`repeatedly`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeatedly), you could do something with a list comprehension:

```
a, b, c = [[] for _ in range(3)]
```

Or, create your own generator to help out here:

```
def repeatedly(f):
    while True:
        yield f()

a, b, c, *_ = repeatedly(list)
```

The `*_` here is unfortunately required to hold the rest of the infinite list.

The point though is, you must explicitly create multiple lists through some means. A copy will never be created via assignment in Python. If you want multiple lists, you must create multiple lists.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you just want brevity, this might be something:

```
(a,b,c) = ( [] ,[], [] )
a.append(1)
print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[1]
[]
```

Comment: its the same as `a,b,c = [], [], []`

Comment: what are you trying to do, then? With int it works because it is a primitive, the size in bits is the same size of the reference value. With anything else than primitives putting one potato to three one bags will not work