# Could I define multiple dataframe using pd.DataFrame()?

Tags: python, pandas

Is is possible to create multiple dataframes under pandas library?

The following codes is what I have tried but it doesn't work...

```
df1, df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```py
df1, df2 = (pd.DataFrame(),) * 2
```

Or, more explicitly:

```py
df1, df2 = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
```

Or even:

```py
df1 = df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16349356/5015569) answer for a great explanation.

Comment: Does this make sense, it's only copying the references.

Comment: Only the 2nd one do not assign the same object to different df name ~

Comment: @cs95 I feel the same, since they have the same id