# Multivariable assignment: order_item, created =

Tags: python, django

```
order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
    item=item,
    user = request.user,
    ordered = False
)
```

now here I can't understand how it will work I tried searching the web but had no luck :(

Comment: What is your exact question here..

Comment: @Sumithran bro i cant understand how "order_item, created = .... " works like when to use created and when to user order_item

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python assigning multiple variables to same value? list behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348815/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-value-list-behavior)

Comment: @TomMcLean I dont think so because here is only one source but two variable or multiple variable

Comment: @AneeqAk that one source is returning multiple values

Comment: @AneeqAk unlike other languages, python can have functions that return multiple values and can then be set to multiple variables, read about them here - https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/