# Unpacking over multiple lines with style

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style, iterable-unpacking

In Python, I want to do something like this

```
an_explicit_variable_name, another_explicit_variable_name, an_even_more_explicit_variable_name = function(foo)
```

But I also want this to be readable and fit on several short lines rather than one very long line. I didn't find any help in [PEP 08](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495332/more-elegant-way-of-declaring-multiple-variables-at-the-same-time) is somwhat related, but the answers aren't quite what I want.

---

This is the best I could come up with as far as line-length is concerned, but I don't really like using `a[0]` etc.

```
a = function(foo)
an_explicit_variable_name = a[0]
another_explicit_variable_name = a[1]
an_even_more_explicit_variable_name = a[2]
```

---

This doesn't work because the second line is still too long

```
_ = function(foo)
an_explicit_variable_name, another_explicit_variable_name, an_even_more_explicit_variable_name = _
```

---

Should I separate the variables I am declaring over several lines? If so, how do I indent?

```
an_explicit_variable_name, \
    another_explicit_variable_name, \
    an_even_more_explicit_variable_name \
    = function(foo)


an_explicit_variable_name, \
        another_explicit_variable_name, \
        an_even_more_explicit_variable_name \
    = function(foo)
```

---

What would be the proper style to adopt in this situation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use parentheses:

```
(an_explicit_variable_name, 
 another_explicit_variable_name, 
 an_even_more_explicit_variable_name) = function(foo)
```

Alternatively, if the data belongs together, create a container object to hold it together, e.g. a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), then do:

```
data = container(*function(foo))
# use e.g. data.an_explicit_variable_name
```