# What is the difference between SimpleNamespace and empty class definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following seems to work either way. What is the advantage (other than the nice `repr`) of using `types.SimpleNamespace`? Or is it the same thing?

```
>>> import types
>>> class Cls():
...     pass
... 
>>> foo = types.SimpleNamespace() # or foo = Cls()
>>> foo.bar = 42
>>> foo.bar
42
>>> del foo.bar
>>> foo.bar
AttributeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is explained pretty well in the [types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) module description. It shows you that `types.SimpleNamespace` is roughly equivalent to this:

```
class SimpleNamespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

This provides the following advantages over an empty class:

1. It allows you to initialize attributes while constructing the object: `sn = SimpleNamespace(a=1, b=2)`
2. It provides a readable `repr()`: `eval(repr(sn)) == sn`
3. It overrides the default comparison. Instead of comparing by `id()`, it compares attribute values instead.

Comment: Any idea why `repr(SimpleNamespace(a=1))` displays `"namespace(a=1)"`? I'd expect it to be SimpleNamespace instead of simply namespace.

Comment: @Demi-Lune It's [hard-coded](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/namespaceobject.c#L67). However, `SimpleNamespace`'s subclasses instances get their own class name.

Comment: To add biggest benefit to me 4: it allows me to use dot.notation on dictionaries.

Comment: @Anssi: I assume you mean when one is used instead of a dictionary, correct?

Comment: @martineau like this:`ns = types.SimpleNamespace(**{'a':1})` but now i have come to conclusion that is might be just easier to use classes instead of hacks like this. I am still learning good coding convention for Python. It is more difficult i first thought.

Comment: @Anssi: It's possible to create a dictionary subclass that supports dot nation as well as all the usual dictionary methods. Do a web search on the term "AttrDict".

Comment: @martineau i prefer to use classes directly. I am using PyCharm and it can actually show and fill the variables set to self in __init__ or  set with dot notation after the instance of class have been made. (otherwise it goes to __slots__ not __dict__). Thanks for pointing out AttrDict. I will check it out.

Answer (score 16):

A [`class types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) provides a mechanism to instantiate an object that can hold attributes and nothing else. It is, in effect, an empty class with a fancier `__init__()` and a helpful `__repr__()`:

```py
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> sn = SimpleNamespace(x = 1, y = 2)
>>> sn
namespace(x=1, y=2)
>>> sn.z = 'foo'
>>> del(sn.x)
>>> sn
namespace(y=2, z='foo')
```

or

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace

sn = SimpleNamespace(x = 1, y = 2)
print(sn)

sn.z = 'foo'
del(sn.x)
print(sn)
```

output:

```sh
namespace(x=1, y=2)
namespace(y=2, z='foo')
```

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054971/13155046) may also be helpful.