# Why does SimpleNamespace have a different size than that of an empty class?

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```
In [1]: import types

In [2]: class A:
    ...:     pass
    ...:

In [3]: a1 = A()

In [4]: a1.a, a1.b, a1.c = 1, 2, 3

In [5]: a2 = types.SimpleNamespace(a=1,b=2,c=3)

In [6]: sys.getsizeof(a1)
Out[6]: 56

In [7]: sys.getsizeof(a2)
Out[7]: 48
```

Where is this size discrepancy coming from? Looking at:

```
In [10]: types.__file__
Out[10]: '/Users/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/types.py'
```

I find:

```
import sys

# Iterators in Python aren't a matter of type but of protocol.  A large
# and changing number of builtin types implement *some* flavor of
# iterator.  Don't check the type!  Use hasattr to check for both
# "__iter__" and "__next__" attributes instead.

def _f(): pass
FunctionType = type(_f)
LambdaType = type(lambda: None)         # Same as FunctionType
CodeType = type(_f.__code__)
MappingProxyType = type(type.__dict__)
SimpleNamespace = type(sys.implementation)
```

Ok, well, here goes nothing:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.implementation
namespace(cache_tag='cpython-35', hexversion=50660080, name='cpython', version=sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0))
>>> type(sys.implementation)
<class 'types.SimpleNamespace'>
```

I seem to be chasing my own tail here.

I was able to find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161275/what-is-the-difference-between-simplenamespace-and-empty-class-definition), but no answer to my particular query.

I am using CPython 3.5 on a 64-bit system. These 8 bytes seem just the right size for some errant reference that I cannot pin-point.

Comment: Its coming because they are different types ... and `sys.getsizeof` doesn't tell you the total memory consumed by an object, so why should it be the same for these two types?  eg In your example, `getsizeof(A())` (an "empty" `A`) is also 56.

Comment: Right, adding attributes is a red herring. But even if I just have an empty class `class A: pass; a = A()` and `s = SimpleNamespace()`, there is still the discrepancy.

Comment: Sure ... but again, why do you expect two empty types to have the same size?  Do you expect a `set()` and `[]` to have the same size?

Comment: @donkopotamus not necessarily, but I want to understand *why*.

Comment: The definition of the `SimpleNamespace` class is in the [`namespaceobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Objects/namespaceobject.c#l198) source file.

Comment: OT: gracias-Thanks-Danke!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following classes, which have different sizes:

```
class A_dict:
    pass

class A_slot_0:
    __slots__ = []

class A_slot_1:
    __slots__ = ["a"]

class A_slot_2:
    __slots__ = ["a", "b"]
```

Each of these has a differing fundamental memory footprint:

```
>>> [cls.__basicsize__ for cls in [A_dict, A_slot_0, A_slot_1, A_slot_2]]
>>> [32, 16, 24, 32]
```

Why?  In the source of `type_new` (in [`typeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#l2286)), which is responsible for creating the underlying type and computing the basic size of an instance, we see that `tp_basicsize` is computed as:

- the `tp_basicsize` of the underlying type (`object` ... 16 bytes);
- another `sizeof(PyObject *)` for **each** slot;
- a `sizeof(PyObject *)` if a `__dict__` is required;
- a `sizeof(PyObject *)` if a `__weakref__` is defined;

A plain class such as `A_dict` will have a `__dict__` and a `__weakref__` defined, whereas a class with slots has no `__weakref__` by default.  Hence the size of plain `A_dict` is 32 bytes.  You could consider it to effectively consist of `PyObject_HEAD` plus two pointers.

Now, consider a `SimpleNamespace`, which is defined in [`namespaceobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Objects/namespaceobject.c#l7).  Here the type is simply:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *ns_dict;
} _PyNamespaceObject;
```

and `tp_basicsize` is defined as `sizeof(_PyNamespaceObject)`, making it one pointer larger than a plain object, and thus 24 bytes.

#### NOTE:

The difference here is effectively that `A_dict` provides support for taking weak references, while `types.SimpleNamespace` does not.

```
>>> weakref.ref(types.SimpleNamespace())
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'types.SimpleNamespace' object
```