# Is Declaring Multiple Variables on one line Faster than Declaring one Variable on Multiple Lines?

Tags: python, optimization

If I were to do

```
age, height = 16, 1.24
```

would that be faster than

```
age = 16
height = 1.24
```

It would be a very small difference, but I imagine if you are declaring many variables, that time will add up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More elegant way of declaring multiple variables at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495332/more-elegant-way-of-declaring-multiple-variables-at-the-same-time)

Comment: No, it does not. I want optimization, not elegance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where.

Comment: Ok I see but in my opinion both are same.

Comment: Your opinion is that optimization = good looks?

Comment: Have you tried timing it?

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use the timeit module. Although you are looking for a needle in haystack performance improvements. On my machine, I found the latter one (declaring across multiple lines) was faster

Comment: Single line will probably be slower since a tuple will be created and then unpacked

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit

code1 = 'age, height = 16, 1.24' 
code2 = '''age = 16
height = 1.24'''

print (timeit.timeit(stmt = code1, number = 1)) 
print (timeit.timeit(stmt = code2, number = 1))
```

I think declaring each variable separately would be much faster. Try seeing that with the help of the code above.

Comment: On my computer, both ways of assigning took the same amount of time, 14.5ns.