# Functioning of list values in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm learing python(previously have a little c expericence) and am trying to solve a math problem but encountered something unexpected:

```
import math
list_a = list_b = [0 for k in range(10)]
print list_a[0] #test if list_a works]
for i in range(10):
    list_a[i] = math.sqrt(math.pi + i**2)
    print list_a[i]                                      #value
    list_b[i] = math.sqrt(list_a[i]**2 + math.pi**2)
    print list_a[i]                                      #why changed to another value?
    print '-----------------'
```

why after this line:

```
list_b[i] = math.sqrt(list_a[i]**2 + math.pi**2)
```

the `list_a[i]` changed?

Comment: `list_a` and `list_b` references the same list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_a` and `list_b` are labels for the same object. If you want them to be copies instead, do this:

```
list_a = [0 for k in range(10)]
list_b = list_a[:]
```

Another way would be to use list comprehensions and python's multiple assignments:

```
list_a, list_b, list_c = [[0 for k in range(10)] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: thank you for your help! BTW, is there more simple way if I want to decleare many lists in the same time?

Comment: @michaelhuang you can define variables at the same time like; _a,b,c,d=1,2,3,4_. So,do that on list variables.

Comment: @Pradhan tested and finally works elegantly! many thanks!!  PS: [a detailed way to declare many lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line)

Answer (score 1):

```
list_a = list_b = [0 for k in range(10)]
```

Because list_a equal to list_b. So if list_b is changed, then list_a will change.