# Initialize multiple lists in python

Tags: python, initialization, generator-expression

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
x = y = z = [0 for i in xrange(a*b*c)]
```

Is there a way in which x,y,z can be initialized **in one line** (because I don't want to multiply a, b and c for each list initialization), as separate lists of 0s. In the above if x is updated, then y and z are also get updated simultaneously with the same changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Initializing Multiple Lists/Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use another comprehension and unpack it:

```
x, y, z = [[0 for i in xrange(a*b*c)] for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Note that `[0 for i in xrange(a*b*c)]` is equivalent to the simpler `[0] * a*b*c`.

Comment: how about using a generator so the list is not actually builded? `a, b, c = ([0 for i in xrange(a*b*c)] for _ in xrange(3))`

Comment: @DanielSanchez - We could do that, certainly. However, seeing any performance benefit from it would require creating many more lists than should be unpacked into multiple independent variables in a single line. It only has to store the references anyway, which are small.

Comment: please can you explain a bit further, as I see it you are building the a list wich contains another lists, but you will never use that list. By using a generator you just get rid of that list. Am I wrong or missing something? thanks!!

Comment: @DanielSanchez - It would get rid of a list, yes, but the list is tiny, and it should never be anything but tiny.

Comment: you meaned that, ok, either way I think it should not be used, just think it is in a loop of 1000 iterations, you will be creating 1000 lists, must take care of that. Thanks for the explanation, good answer.

Comment: @DanielSanchez - It's not a loop with 1000 iterations for 1000 lists, it's a loop of 3 iterations for 3 lists. Remember that this is a single line - if there were more than half a dozen lists, it would start looking weird and taking up too much space. Also remember that this is being unpacked - if there were more than a dozen lists, it would make more sense to just retain the list holding them in the first place rather than unpacking it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120104/discussion-between-daniel-sanchez-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your stated intention rather than at the 'one line' requirement:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
x = [0 for i in xrange(a*b*c)]
y = x [:]
z = x [:]
```

Not sure the optimizer is clever enough to avoid repeated multiplication at:

```
x, y, z = [[0 for i in xrange(a*b*c)] for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Suppose a, b, and c were properties, so reading them would have side effects. How could the optimizer know this in a dynamically typed language?