# Python Value Error: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

Get the following error in code, unsure of what it means or what I did wrong. Just trying to initialize three list values to empty collections:

```
nba,nfl,mlb = []
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Comment: What did you find when you searched for information about the error? What about that information seemed insufficient or was confusing?

Comment: @jpmc26 there was not sufficient material on a google search for initializing multiple lists in a single line. I'm sure you'll _stand

Comment: That is simply not true. https://www.google.com/search?q=python+create+multiple+lists+in+one+line&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial And the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2402646/1394393 The second answer contains exactly the syntax you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attempts to unpack, as the error message says, an iterable on the right hand side into three variables on the left hand side, so, for example, after running `a,b,c = 1,2,3` you get `a == 1 and b == 2 and c == 3`.

In your case, this iterable is empty, so "there are not enough values to unpack": there are three variables, but no values in the iterable (the iterable is an empty list). What you need is the following:

```
a,b,c = [],[],[]
```

Here you have three variables `a,b,c` and the iterable discussed above is the tuple `[],[],[]` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is , left hand side values are not enough to assign to the number of variable on the left so instead do

```
nba,nfl,mlb = [],[],[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you want to unpack a generator for instance:

```
nba,nfl,mlb = [[] for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

basically means left hand side has more values than right hand side of `=`

`nba = nfl = mlb = []` should get you three list values initialized to empty collections. So should `nba, nfl, mlb = [], [], []`

Comment: would the first solution result in three variable pointing at the same list?