# Initialization of multiple empty lists in Python

Tags: python, list, memory

What is the correct way to initialize a bunch of variables to independent empty lists in Python 3?

```
>>> (a, b) = ([],)*2
>>> a.append([2,3])
>>> a
[[2, 3]]
>>> b
[[2, 3]]
>>> b.append([2,3,])
>>> b
[[2, 3], [2, 3]]
>>> a
[[2, 3], [2, 3]]


>>> (a, b) = ([]  for _ in range(2))
>>> a.append([2,3])
>>> a
[[2, 3]]
>>> b
[]
>>> b.append([2])
>>> b
[[2]]
>>> a
[[2, 3]]
```

Why the first attempt does not allocate `a`, `b` independently in memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Initializing Multiple Lists/Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line)

Comment: not with regards to the latter part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Why the first attempt does not allocate a, b independently in memory?*** because they refer to same address in memory.

```py
(a, b) = ([],)*2
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
# 4346159296
# 4346159296
```

```py
(a, b) = ([]  for _ in range(2))
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
# 4341571776
# 4341914304
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize them as the following.

```
a = b = []
a = [2]
b = [2, 3]
print(a, b)
```

Comment: >>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(2)
>>> a
[2]
>>> b
[2]

Answer (score 0):

> Why the first attempt does not allocate a, b independently in memory?

Because you are using same list to define several variables. It is something like:

```
list1 = []
var1, var2 = list1, list1
```

In your second case you are using comprehension which is creating new lists every iteration.

You can have a look at this example

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
a = [val for val in list1]
b = [val for val in list1]
c, d = ([list1]) * 2
print(f"{a=}")
print(f"{b=}")
print(f"{c=}")
print(f"{d=}")
print("Append something")
a.append("a append")
list1.append("list1 append")
print(f"{a=}")
print(f"{b=}")
print(f"{c=}")
print(f"{d=}")
```

Output:

```
a=[1, 2, 3]
b=[1, 2, 3]
c=[1, 2, 3]
d=[1, 2, 3]
Append something
a=[1, 2, 3, 'a append']
b=[1, 2, 3]
c=[1, 2, 3, 'list1 append']
d=[1, 2, 3, 'list1 append']
```