# python for loop range(bigint)

Tags: python

In Python, is there some *short* way to do something like

"for i in range(n)"

when n is too big for Python to actually create the array range(n)?

(short because otherwise I'd just use a while loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [xrange()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange)... although that *is* restricted to "short" integers in CPython:

> CPython implementation detail:
>   xrange() is intended to be simple and
>   fast. Implementations may impose
>   restrictions to achieve this. The C
>   implementation of Python restricts all
>   arguments to native C longs (“short”
>   Python integers), and also requires
>   that the number of elements fit in a
>   native C long. If a larger range is
>   needed, an alternate version can be
>   crafted using the itertools module:
>   `takewhile(lambda x: x<stop,
>   (start+i*step for i in count()))`.

I don't know whether that restriction also applies to other implementations (or which ones) - but there's a workaround listed...

I know you mention `bigint` in your question title, but the question body talks about the number being too big to create the array - I suspect there are plenty of numbers which are small enough for `xrange` to work, but big enough to cause you memory headaches with `range`.

Comment: ...or use Python 3, where `range` behaves like `xrange` from Python 2 without the restriction to "short" integers...

Comment: As I just learned from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange there is a limitation of xrange to C longs, so you cannot have upper boundaries greater than 2 ** 31 - 1.

Comment: @jellybean:  Or 2**63-1 on a 64-bit (non-Windows) machine.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a generator function:  example forthcoming.

```
def gen():
    i = 0
    while 1: # or your special terminating logic
        yield i
        i = i + 1


for j in gen():
    do stuff
```

Comment: Also, @Jon Skeet's suggestion to use xrange is a good choice.

Comment: Not really necessary to reinvent the wheel - or so I thought until I read about xrange's restrictions. So if you're using Python 2, this is a good choice.

Comment: Agreed, @Tim. :)  Unless you want to exceed the limits of xrange.

Answer (score 1):

You could upgrade to python3. There, range isn't limited to 'short' integers.

Another workaround would be to use xrange for small integers and add them to some constant inside the loop, e.g.

```
offset, upperlimit = 2**65, 2**65+100
for i in xrange(upperlimit-offset):
    j = i + offset
    # ... do something with j
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always use xrange rather than range for just looping n times over sth., but keep in mind that xrange has also a limit (if it is too small you need to do your own while loop with a counter)

EDIT: too late...