# Get a random sample with replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have this list:

```
colors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y"]
```

and I want to get 4 random letters from it, but including repetition.

Running this will only give me 4 unique letters, but never any repeating letters:

```
print(random.sample(colors,4))
```

How do I get a list of 4 colors, with repeating letters possible?

Comment: Related: Without replacement(keep order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482889/get-random-sample-from-list-while-maintaining-ordering-of-items ; without keep order (normal): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741319/what-does-random-sample-method-in-python-do, weighted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549515/weighted-random-sample-without-replacement-in-python)

Answer (score 85):

In Python 3.6, the new [*random.choices()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function will address the problem directly:

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> colors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y"]
>>> choices(colors, k=4)
['G', 'R', 'G', 'Y']
```

Answer (score 24):

With [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
print([random.choice(colors) for _ in colors])
```

If the number of values you need does not correspond to the number of values in the list, then use `range`:

```
print([random.choice(colors) for _ in range(7)])
```

From Python 3.6 onwards you can also use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) (plural) and specify the number of values you need as the *k* argument.

Answer (score 23):

Try `numpy.random.choice` ([documentation numpy-v1.13](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)):

```
import numpy as np
n = 10 #size of the sample you want
print(np.random.choice(colors,n))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will produce the results you require. I have added comments to each line to help you and other users follow the process. Please feel free to ask any questions.

```
import random

colours = ["R", "G", "B", "Y"]  # The list of colours to choose from
output_Colours = []             # A empty list to append results to
Number_Of_Letters = 4           # Allows the code to easily be updated

for i in range(Number_Of_Letters):  # A loop to repeat the generation of colour
    output_Colours.append(random.sample(colours,1)) # append and generate a colour from the list

print (output_Colours)
```

Comment: Excellent! I cried. Elementary, said he.