# Generate random strings from list with specific length in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to randomly select a string of characters from this list of symbols without replacement: '@','+','?','!','$','*','%','#','}','>','&','^'.

The length of the generated string would be equal in length to the word in another column from the csv.

Example of an existing csv:

```
Word     Length
dog      3
wolf     4
cactus   6
bus      3
```

I would like to have the code such that it appends a third column to the existing csv file with the generated string equal in length for each word. This is an example of the result I want:

```
Word     Length     String
dog      3          @!#
wolf     4          &*%!
cactus   6          ^?!@#%
bus      3          }&^
```

This is the code I tried but I do not think it is right.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd

os.chdir("/Users/etcetc") #change directory
df = pd.read_csv('generatingstring.csv')

list1 = ['@','+','?','!','$','*','%','#','}','>','&','^']
list2 = df['String'] #creating a new column for the generated string

for row in df['Length']: #hope this reads each row in that column
    for n in range(1, row): #hope this reads the length value within cell
        s = random.choice(list1)
        list1.remove(s) #to ensure random selection without replacement
        list2.append(s)
```

I was hoping to make it read each row within the Length column, and within each row take note of how many symbols to randomly select.

Thank you!

Comment: you don't need the second loop if you use numpy, see the `replace=False` argument in [np.random.choice]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weighted random sample without replacement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549515/weighted-random-sample-without-replacement-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
import numpy as np 
df.Word.map(lambda x : ''.join(np.random.choice(list1,len(x),replace = False)))
Out[145]: 
0       &$!
1      >^$!
2    @}%?$>
3       #+!
Name: Word, dtype: object
```

Comment: This works! I am also curious, how do I append this output into a brand new column in my existing csv? Thank you so much!

Comment: Apologies @BEN_YO, when I did output.to_csv(filename, mode='a', header='Symbols', index =False), the symbol string did not append to a new column. Instead, it attached below the word column. How can I save it properly?