# Python: Sample N random items from list with weights but without repetition

Tags: python, random

I am creating a type of lottery system where individuals (identifier by unique id) can have multiple tickets into a lottery however once they are picked, they cannot be selected to win again.

Here is my example:

```
import random
entrants = ['John', 'Jane', 'Cthulhu']
allEntries = []
for entrant in entrants:
    numEntries = random.randint(1, 5)
    print("%s has %d entries" % (entrant, numEntries))
    allEntries.extend([entrant] * numEntries)
print(random.sample(allEntries, k=2))
```

My idea was to make a list that has `entrant`'s name `numEntries` times and then select from there. However sometimes the same individual is picked as both winners. Is there a way to have weights for each entrant?

I tried using `random.choices()` with `weights` but this can also select the same individual as both winners.

```
import random
weights = []
for entrant in entrants:
    numEntries = random.randint(1, 5)
    print("%s has %d entries" % (entrant, numEntries))
    weights.extend([numEntries])
print(random.choices(entrants, weights=weights, k=2))
```

Comment: Why not just randomly shuffle the list and grab N number of items from it?

Comment: @RandomDavis How would it have the weights? A list can be shuffled but still have the same person be the winner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549515/weighted-random-sample-without-replacement-in-python - though that's aimed mostly at numpy solutions.

Comment: How many winners do you want to pick? Is it always 2 or does that vary as well?

Comment: The winners will vary and my use-case will be between 1 and 200.

Comment: Unfortunately, since you're drawing from two different (but related) weighted samples, `random` and `numpy.random` don't support your use case with a straightforward solution.  Take the winners one at a time, removing each from your data set as they're chosen.

Comment: So if # entrants <= # winners then everybody wins regardless of weights?

Comment: @Prune - I think `numpy.random.choice` could do it if you turn the number of tickets per entrant into the probability vector. There's no good alternative to modifying the data set as you go in pure Python, though.

Comment: @Peter  `choice` still allows the problem with picking the same person twice.

Comment: @Prune - not if the person is in the input array once and you use the `replace=False` argument. (That's true for the numpy version, not the Python 3.6 addition of `random.choices` - that allows a weight dataset but only allows with-replacement. I think it's numpy or write your own version that mutates the candidate set as it selects people.)

Comment: The [3.8 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choices) doesn't show a `replace` parameter.  What version has that feature?

Comment: Ah, I thought we might be talking at cross purposes re: numpy vs the `random.choices` - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html - though I see it has a deprecation notice and a recommendation to use a different method.https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal method to select randomly without repetition is to shuffle the entries and take the first N.

```
from random import shuffle

N = 1
entrants = ['John', 'Jane', 'Cthulhu']
shuffle(entrants)
print(entrants[:N])
```

Or more directly

```
from random import sample

N = 1
entrants = ['John', 'Jane', 'Cthulhu']
print(sample(entrants, N))
```

However your requirement of weighted sampling means you'll need more than that.

```
def unique_sample(population, count):
  shuffle(population)
  unique = set()
  it = iter(population)
  while len(unique) < count:
    elem = next(it)
    if elem not in unique:
      yield elem
    unique.add(elem)
```

Comment: This works if everyone has 1 entry but each individual has different weights.

Comment: @Bijan if the weights are integers, then you can repeat the entry for it's weight

Comment: But repeated entries mean you're not guaranteed unique values. There isn't a simple native Python solution I can think of. (Don't use shuffle when sample will do, though! It's a much more expensive operation if the sequence size is significant.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do what you want is using NumPy. The following function does it all:

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

`a`: array-like object (e.g. list) you want to select from

`size`: number of elements to select

`replace`: indicates whether it is it allowed to select the same item multiple times - in your case `False`

`p`: array-like object (e.g. list) with the probabilities for the elements in a (same order)

Reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Answer (score 0):

I liked my solution of multiplying the entrant's name by the number of entries. The problem with my solutions was that if I selected a winner, they were still in the pool.

```
import random

def selectWinners(allEntries, numWinners):
    winners = []
    print("Selecting %d winners" % numWinners)
    print("Entries", allEntries)
    for i in range(numWinners):
        winner = random.choice(allEntries)
        print("%d: %s won" % (i+1, winner))
        allEntries[:] = [x for x in allEntries if x != winner]

entrants = ['John', 'Jane', 'Cthulhu']
allEntries = []
for entrant in entrants:
    numEntries = random.randint(1, 5)
    print("%s has %d entries" % (entrant, numEntries))
    allEntries.extend([entrant] * numEntries)
selectWinners(allEntries, 2)
```

returns an output like:

```
John has 1 entries
Jane has 1 entries
Cthulhu has 5 entries
Selecting 2 winners
Entries ['John', 'Jane', 'Cthulhu', 'Cthulhu', 'Cthulhu', 'Cthulhu', 'Cthulhu']
1: Cthulhu won
2: Jane won
```