# Return list of weighted objects with semi-randomized ranking

Tags: python, list, random, ranking, weighted

Let's say I have a list of objects (in Python) that looks something like this (contains an identifier and a ranking/weighting):

```
objects = [
    ("object_1", 0.50),
    ("object_2", 0.75),
    ("object_3", 0.25),
    ("object_4", 0.01),
    ("object_5", 0.99),
]
```

I would like to return this same `objects` array but in semi-randomised order of their weighting. That is, I don't *always* want to return:

```
[
    ("object_5", 0.99),
    ("object_2", 0.75),
    ("object_1", 0.50),
    ("object_3", 0.25),
    ("object_4", 0.01),
]
```

but would instead rather allow for *some* non-determinism so that, generally speaking, the returned array *looks like* the above but could also look like:

```
[
    ("object_5", 0.99),
    ("object_1", 0.50),
    ("object_2", 0.75),
    ("object_4", 0.01),
    ("object_3", 0.25),
]
```

---

EDIT: I *think* I'm asking a different question than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549515/weighted-random-sample-without-replacement-in-python) because the ordering matters here; and in the other question the order doesn't matter (again, I think!).

Comment: So it could be completely random?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I suppose there's a possibility that the original `objects` array could be returned sorted in the opposite order (from low weights to high) but I would like for that possibility to be very unlikely. This is what I mean by "semi-randomized," though I'm not sure if I'm being clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weighted random sample without replacement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549515/weighted-random-sample-without-replacement-in-python)

Comment: Thanks all! I saw that question before but wasn't sure it would work because -- in my case -- the order matters whereas the linked solution is for an unordered sample, I think anyway. Like.. I want the higher ranked stuff to appear in the first positions more often than the latter positions. But lemme play around with both the answer posted below as well as this one linked and will build similar visualizations to verify myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to ensure that the `weight` values are always in between [0, 1), then the following code will work!

```
from random import random


def weighted_sample_without_replacement(
    population: List[Tuple[Any, float]], weights: tuple
) -> List[Tuple[Any, float]]:
    return sorted(population, key=lambda x: x[1] * random())
```

where `population` looks like:

```
[
    ("object_5", 0.99),
    ("object_2", 0.75),
    ("object_1", 0.50),
    ("object_3", 0.25),
    ("object_4", 0.01),
]
```

`weights` like:

```
(
    0.99,
    0.75,
    0.50,
    0.25,
    0.01,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken one approach could be to weighted sample without replacement:

```
from random import choices


def weighted_sample_without_replacement(population, weights, k=1):
    #    https://stackoverflow.com/a/43649323/4001592
    weights = list(weights)
    positions = range(len(population))
    indices = []
    while True:
        needed = k - len(indices)
        if not needed:
            break
        for i in choices(positions, weights, k=needed):
            if weights[i]:
                weights[i] = 0.0
                indices.append(i)
    return [population[i] for i in indices]


data = [
    ("object_5", 0.99),
    ("object_2", 0.75),
    ("object_1", 0.50),
    ("object_3", 0.25),
    ("object_4", 0.01),
]

_, weights = zip(*data)
sample = weighted_sample_without_replacement(data, weights, k=len(data))
print(sample)
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
[('object_2', 0.75), ('object_5', 0.99), ('object_3', 0.25), ('object_1', 0.5), ('object_4', 0.01)]
```

A basic experimental analysis seems to *validate* my hypothesis:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

_, weights = zip(*data)
counts = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
for _ in range(1000):
    sample = weighted_sample_without_replacement(data, weights, k=len(data))
    for i, (key, _) in enumerate(sample):
        counts[i][key] += 1

for key, values in counts.items():
    print(key, sorted(values.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

**Output** *(experiment)*

```
0 [('object_5', 415), ('object_2', 290), ('object_1', 186), ('object_3', 106), ('object_4', 3)]
1 [('object_2', 322), ('object_5', 309), ('object_1', 241), ('object_3', 119), ('object_4', 9)]
2 [('object_1', 319), ('object_2', 259), ('object_3', 209), ('object_5', 199), ('object_4', 14)]
3 [('object_3', 533), ('object_1', 239), ('object_2', 126), ('object_5', 75), ('object_4', 27)]
4 [('object_4', 947), ('object_3', 33), ('object_1', 15), ('object_2', 3), ('object_5', 2)]
```

The value `'object_5'` is in the two first positions 724 times out of 1000, while `'object_4'` is in the last position 947 times out of 1000. For a better visualisation of the results, see the plot below (the visualisation was generated by an additional run of the experimental setup):

[image: Distribution of positions by object]

The code for reproducing the experiments can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mesejo/1914fb91f518c9a94cf6beb928a4510d).

Comment: Thanks @Dani Masejo! Do you mind pasting the code for your visualization by chance? I'm just now coming back around to this and would like to play with a few different strategies (yours included!) and have been banging my head against matplotlib for an hour already :P

Comment: @stevenchusm Updated the answer with the links to a file reproducing the experiments an the plot

Comment: I want to thank you so much again for your time. But I wanted to raise what mayyyy be an issue? See my comments here: https://gist.github.com/chusteven/3bf766d56b0811b592dc3fb4988b9fa2 -- I'm definitely no statistics expert, but feel as though the key is whether or not we chose a single element at each pass or not? Wondering what you think :) In any case I actually found a solution I will post shortly in the case what one can make their weights in between [0, 1) here https://gist.github.com/chusteven/0e9af20af4b7357ccf9ea22f633d3f2f

Comment: @stevenchusm I don't understand, what is the issue with the solution?

Comment: I think in your solution you are potentially selecting more than one element in each iteration of the while loop. But I think you need to select only one element in each iteration, right? My reason being that after you select one element, the `weights` need to be rebalanced entirely? Ah, I'm sorry I'm not sure if I'm making myself clear and it'd be easier to explain via DM. I guess another thing is that `choices` returns an unordered selection right?

Comment: Yes, it returns more than one element. But the weights are recomputed each time choices is called (internally in the function) so I don't if you are referring to that by rebalanced. Yes it is unordered. See the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices for how the weights (probabilities) are computed

Comment: I guess when I think of selecting items in a ranked fashion, I think "select the top one first, then the second one second, etc." But each time *you* call choices, you are selecting potentially more than one, whereas I think you should recompute weights every time after selecting a single element. And because they're unordered you're not asking for the "top" one first, right? Line 54 of my first gist would make it more likely to get the top one first. And on the next iteration, the second one second. I don't mean to cause confusion :( -- like I said statistics is not my strong suit.

Comment: I saw your solution also and it seems ok, feel free to posted here as answer and mark it as selected.