# Generating Unique Random Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a code that would generate number of random strings (for eg.10 in this case). I used the code below but the code kept on generating same strings

Input Code

```
import random
import string

s = string.ascii_lowercase
c = ''.join(random.choice(s) for i in range(8))

for x in range (0,10):
    print(c)
```

Output

```
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
ashjkaes
press any key to continue .....
```

Please help

Comment: You need to put the `random.choice` in the `for` loop to make a new one each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you do now is you generate a random string `c` then print it 10 times
You should instead place the generation inside the loop to generate a new string every time.

```
import random
import string

s = string.ascii_lowercase

for i in range(10):
    c = ''.join(random.choice(s) for i in range(8))
    print(c)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the strings will be unique. While pretty low, there is a chance a string will be generated twice

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3.6, you can use `random.choices` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43649405/1142167)). Example:

```
import random
import string

sample = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=10))
print(sample)
```

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, you need to have `random.choice` inside loop, what I want to note, that you could use underscore (`_`) meaning *I do not care for that variable* together with `for`, which in this case would mean:

```
import random
import string

s = string.ascii_lowercase
for _ in range(10):
    c = ''.join(random.choice(s) for _ in range(8))
    print(c)
```

I do not want you to feel obliged to do so, but be aware about such convention exist in Python language.

Answer (score 1):

Try below to achieve result what you want

```
import random
import string

s = string.ascii_lowercase

for x in range (0,10):
    print(''.join(random.choice(s) for i in range(8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you random string including numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters.

```
import string, random
random_string=''
for x in range(8):
    if random.choice([1,2]) == 1:
        random_string += random_string.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
    else:
        random_string += random_string.join(random.choice(string.digits))
print(random_string)
```