# Randomly select a length of numbers from numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a number of data files, each containing a large amount of data points.

After loading the file with numpy, I get a numpy array:

```
f=np.loadtxt("...-1.txt")
```

How do I randomly select a length of `x`, but the order of numbers should not be changed?

For example:

```
f = [1,5,3,7,4,8]
```

if I wanted to select a random length of 3 data points, the output should be:

1. `1,5,3`, or
2. `3,7,4`, or
3. `5,3,7`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random sample from list while maintaining ordering of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482889/get-random-sample-from-list-while-maintaining-ordering-of-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure logic will get you there.

For a list `f` and a max length `x`, the valid starting points of your random slices are limited to `0, len(f)-x`:

```
     0 1 2 3
f = [1,5,3,7,4,8]
```

So all valid starting point can be selected with `random.randrange(len(f)-x+1)` (where the `+1` is because [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers) works like `range`).

Store the random starting point into a variable `start` and slice your array with `[start:start+x]`, or be creative and use another slice after the first:

```
result = f[random.randrange(len(f)-x+1):][:3]
```

Comment: This works just perfect! Thank you for providing the details for the logic used in the code! It helps a lot!

Comment: Isn't it more efficient (especially when taking for example the first 3 elements out of a million element array) to take out only the specific elements you need?

Comment: @Robin: it probably would, but due to its syntax you then need ro store the random in a variable first. But yes, with million-plus lists you'd probably benefit from that tiny overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Building on usr2564301's answer you can take out only the elements you need in 1 go using a range so you avoid building a potentially very large intermediate array:

```
result = f[range(random.randrange(len(f)-x+1), x)]
```

A range also avoids that you build large index arrays when your length `x` becomes larger.