# Avoiding nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, cartesian-product

I am trying to test some other Python code repeatedly, using all possible combinations of values for six different parameters. For each parameter I want to iterate over a range of values with a given minimum, maximum and step.

I managed to write some code like:

```
for var1 in range(min1, max1, step1):
    for var2 in range(min2, max2, step2):
        for var3 in range(min3, max3, step3):
            for var4 in range(min4, max4, step4):
                for var5 in range(min5, max5, step5):
                    for var6 in range(min6, max6, step6):
                        do_something_with(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

But I do not like that the code is so deeply nested.

How can I avoid nesting multiple loops? Can it be done using recursion? How about `itertools.product`? I wasn't able to figure out either approach.

---

<sub>See also, more generally: [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905)</sub>

<sub>This question, and some answers, originally showed code for Python 2.x. It has been edited because the fundamental problem persists in 3.x, with the same solution, but `xrange` no longer exists - `range` is the drop-in replacement. For more information, see [What is the difference between range and xrange functions in Python 2.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935).</sub>

Comment: what should be actually done inside all those loops? i think it is the most important question - there are some syntax sugars to hide the loops (but still performing them), but to avoid nested loops, the most important thing is to understant the original problem

Comment: @deathApril is right: I've given you a way to avoid the loops below, but you still have to do all those iterations.  Better would be to use a different algorithm to avoid the iterations.

Comment: Added an edit to explain why I need this

Comment: The point is not about using or not using for loops; it is more that you may not understand how quickly the number of test cases increases. 6 settings, each with 10 possible values, is a million test cases.

Comment: i see the itertools.product solved your problem. good for you. just don't be surprised when you find out the performance difference between explicit nested for loops and hidden C code that performs nested loops can only be so big ;) P.S.: actually, it would be nice if you did post the performance test results :))

Comment: @deathApril: you're the only one talking about performance.  The OP didn't mention is at all, this isn't about performance, it's about the structure of the code.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's how to use `product`:

```
x1 = range(min1, max1, step1)
x2 = range(min2, max2, step2)
x3 = range(min3, max3, step3)
...

for v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 in itertools.product(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6):
    do_something_with(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)
```

or a bit more compactly:

```
ranges = [
    range(min1, max1, step1),
    range(min2, max2, step2),
    range(min3, max3, step3),
    ...
]

for v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 in itertools.product(*ranges):
    do_something_with(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)
```

Comment: Nice! Was about to ask a question on how to do this!

Comment: you could simplify this with replacing `v1, v2, v3...` with `args` then do `icky_thing(*args)`

Comment: For python3 users, you should use `range` instead of `xrange`.

Answer (score 17):

You can probably use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Something like

```
for var1, var2 in itertools.product(range(min1, max1, step1), range(min2, max2, step2)):
    # stuff
```

but with all six vars in there.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `multiprocessing` and `itertools.product` to speed up and simplify your code

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool

ranges = [
    range(min1,max1,step1),
    range(min2,max2,step2),
    range(min3,max3,step3),
    ...
]

with Pool(os.cpu_count()-2) as p:
    result = p.map(your_op_func, itertools.product(*ranges))
```

1. `multiprocessing` can speed up your task (because it's mutex task)
2. `itertools.product` can help you get combinations through a more effectively way