# how to convert my list output into int outputs in python

Tags: python

```
import random
n=int(input("Enter the limit of your matrix:"))
a=[[random.random()for i in range(n)],[random.random()for j in range(n)]]
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        a[i][j]=int(input("Enter the element:"))
sumr=0
sumc=0
for i in range(0,n):
    sumr+=a[i]
for j in range(0,n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        sumc+=a[j][i]
```

this program shows attribute error that list cannot be added to int item.
help me in rectifying it.
also suggest the corrections to be made

Comment: `a[i]` is a list, `sumr` is an int. Maybe you want `sumr+=sum(a[i])`?

Comment: its because of `sumr+=a[i]` what you want to do with that ?

Comment: There is a contradiction in your code: do you want a[i] to be a list or an int?

Comment: You realize that your code crashes with any number (n) greater than 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ python test.py 
Enter the limit of your matrix:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 209, in <module>
    a[i][j]=int(input("Enter the element:"))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Your code work for 2*2 matrix, because you crested only two rows.

```
a=[[random.random()for i in range(n)],[random.random()for j in range(n)]]
```

Following is output of a for 3*3 matrix:-

```
[[0.9632434262652646, 0.7470504655963679, 0.2750109619917276], [0.7032133906246875, 0.16200573351318048, 0.09565026547688305]]
```

**overcome to above issue see following code:**
Algo/steps:

1. Get Matrix limit n*n
2. Create matrix of n*n
3. By lambda, map and sum function get sum of all rows and column.
4. No need of random method.

code:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter the limit of your matrix:"))
a = []
tmp = [0 for k in range(n)]
for i in range(0,n):
    a.append(list(tmp))
    for j in range(0,n):
        a[i][j] = int(input("Enter the element:"))

sumr = sum(map(lambda x:sum(x), a))
sumc = 0
for j in range(0,n):
    sumc +=sum(map(lambda x:x[j], a))

print sumr
print sumc
```

Output:

```
Enter the limit of your matrix:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
18
18
```

Comment: Merged both answers to one.

Answer (score 4):

`a[i]` is a list (representing a row in your code).

You cannot add list and `int`, you should:

```
sumr += sum(a[i])
```

`sum` will return the sum of elements in the list `a[i]` as an `int`, and now your calculations will be fine.

Comment: how you konw that OP wants that ?

Comment: @Kasra I know everything. Kidding.. According to his code, I assume that. If he commented otherwise, I'll change my code accordingly.

Comment: really ? so maybe you could tell me is there any life out side the earth ? ;)

Comment: @Kasra Yes, there is. I'm sure ;)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\my programs\sum of each row and column.py", line 13, in <module>
    sumc+=sum(a[j][i])
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @SurkaavS You don't need it there. `a[j][i]` is already an int.

Comment: here is the outputEnter the limit of your matrix:2
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:4
10
10

Comment: Sum of all rows and sum of all columns are always same :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for i in range(0,n):
    sumr+=a[i]
```

Simply write

```
sumr = sum(a[i] for i in range(0, n))
```

`a[i]` is a list. You can't add a list to an `int` directly, even if it's a list of `int`. Conversely, you can add the `sum()` of a `list` of `int` to an `int`.

Comment: `sum([ a[i] for i in range (0,n) ])` is redundant. `sum(a[i])` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Matrix limit n*n
2. Create matrix of n*n
3. By lambda, map and sum function get sum of all rows and column.
4. No need of random method.

>

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter the limit of your matrix:"))
a = []
tmp = [0 for k in range(n)]
for i in range(0,n):
    a.append(list(tmp))
    for j in range(0,n):
        a[i][j] = int(input("Enter the element:"))

sumr = sum(map(lambda x:sum(x), a))
sumc = 0
for j in range(0,n):
    sumc +=sum(map(lambda x:x[j], a))

print sumr
print sumc
```

Output:-

```
Enter the limit of your matrix:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
18
18
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some assumptions regarding your question, and here is a solution that prints sums of rows and columns after entering the elements. Also, you've been trying to add a list to integer, which was causing that error.

Note that we don't need `random()` to initialize the list, so I've replaced it. I've refactored your code a little bit and wrote comments that would help.

```
n = input("Enter the limit of your matrix:") # no need to cast input to int
a = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
for i in xrange(n):    # range(n) or xrange(n) start from 0 by default
    for j in xrange(n):
        a[i][j]=int(input("Enter the element:"))
sumr = []
sumc = [0 for x in xrange(n)]

for i in xrange(n):
    sumr.append(sum(a[i]))
    for j in xrange(n):
        sumc[j] += a[i][j]

print "sum of rows: ", sumr
print "sum of columns", sumc
```

This works for any index. Also, the `sumr` and `sumc` in your code, if they're what I guess they are, would both get same value at the end, but this is different here.

Here's an example:

```
~ python test.py
Enter the limit of your matrix:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:3
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:2
Enter the element:4
Enter the element:1
Enter the element:5
Enter the element:6
sum of rows:  [6, 7, 12]
sum of columns [3, 9, 13]
```

Also, refer to this link for more info about [how to initialize multi-dimensional lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667288/1076075), and some info about [difference between xrange and range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94935/1076075), although it wont make much of a difference in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in line 3 and line 6 are conflicting (intuitively).

```
a=[[random.random()for i in range(n)],[random.random()for j in range(n)]]
```

**does not create n lists with n elements in each list**(am guessing here, looks like that's what you need) This one does that:

```
a=[[random.random() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]]
```

The part that leads to error is:

```
sumr=0
sumc=0
for i in range(0,n):
    sumr+=a[i]
```

`sumr` is of `<type 'int'>`, but `a[i]` is a list of `len = n`, and the `+=` operator raises the error there.

If you want sum of rows, you can try:

```
sumr = [sum(row) for row in a]        # sum of rows
sumc = [sum(col) for col in zip(*a)]  # sum of columns
```

For simpler code you must use [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and [numpy.sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

```
a = numpy.array(a)
sumr = numpy.sum(a, 1)
sumc = numpy.sum(a, 0)
```