# How to use loop in python by using List?

Tags: python, list, loops, digit

I'm currently new in python and i'm trying to split digits into list. Now i want to show all that digits one by one in single row after splitting.

Suppose, I give input to my program like this -> `123456`

I want to achieve my output like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

So, i tried this codes:

```
myList = input("\nEnter: ")

myElements = [int(i) for i in str(myList)]
print(myElements)
```

So, i'm able to get output like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

***QUESTION***

But i want to get that digits in every single new row, like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I tried to use `print(myElements[0])` but problem is, I have given a choice to insert, So how it is possible? Please help me..

***HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!~***

Comment: use range and print it
or do you want a column of numbers

Comment: Use a loop and print items?

Comment: But dude.. What to give `numbers` for range? I've given a choice to insert digits.. see -> `myList = input("\nEnter: ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have your list.  Now you need to iterate over the elements in your list and print them out.

```
for i in mylist:
    print i
```

Where i is an arbitrary variable (it could be anything, we use i as a convention) and mylist is the variable name of the list you generated.  i takes the takes the first element from the list starting at index 0 to the end of your list.  To simple print what your elements were, you print i, since i is equal an element in your list every time it loops.

To print a list of 6 numbers starting at one you can use

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    print i
```

if using python 3.

or 
if using python 2 use.

```
for i in xrange(1, 7):
    print i
```

If using python 2  `range()` will work, but I suggest you get into the habit of using `xrange()` if you're working with python2. Notice range starts at 1 and ends at 7.  That means that it will start counting from 1 and end at 6. The difference between range and range can be read here [What is the difference between range and xrange functions in Python 2.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x)

Comment: Thanks, This is what i was looking for! :D I'd accept your answer after `8 minutes`.

Comment: But python 3 doesn't support `xrange`?

Comment: Correct python3 doesn't support xrange only python 2. I said use xrange with python 2.

Comment: In python 3, range is the same as xrange.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = input("\nEnter: ")

myElements = [int(i) for i in str(myList)]
for i in range(len(myElements)):
    print myElements[i]
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(str(myElements)[1:-1].replace(', ','\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use loops for this kind of results ,, trying to perform this by list comprehension will not work

```
[ print x for x in str(12345)]
```

because here , in list comprehension we try to assign print x (python2.7) for as a list , which is wrong because print x is not a variable instead it is a 
`side effect` which put the value of x to appear in screen., finally you have to loop over the list to get the result,

```
for i in list(12345):
    print i
```