# Creating a list that includes all integers between start and end in Python?

Tags: python

If I have two integer (start, end),

for example,

```
start, end = 3,8
```

then I want to create a list that includes all integers from 3 to 8 (also includes 3 and 8)

```
[3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

How can I get that?

Comment: `range(start, end+1)`

Comment: @TanveerAlam Answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: Go read a tutorial or the language docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3: use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-range) as the [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python/231855#231855), and [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-list) to complete:

```
list(range(start, end+1))
```

For Python 2, take note of [range vs xrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x) and that you'd need a call to `list` if you go the route of `xrange`, which acts the same as `range` in Python 3.

Comment: No need to make it a `list` since `range` returns a`list`

Comment: @DanielJimenez In Python 3, `range` is a generator: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function for it:

In python 2.x

```
>>> start, end = 3, 8
>>> range(start, end+1)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

In python 3.x you have to call `list` function on [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to get list as `range` by itself returns generator object.

```
In [1]: start, end = 3, 8
In [2]: range(start, end+1)
Out[2]: range(3, 9)
In [3]: list(range(start, end+1))
Out[3]: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```