# Memory Error when trying to brute force a key

Tags: python-2.7

```
 def bruteForce( dictionary = {}):
    key = 0

    for i in range(len(dictionary)):
        keyRank = 0
        for k in range(68719476736):
            attempt = decrypt(dictionary[i], k)
            if(i != attempt):
                keyRank = 0
                break
            else:
                keyRank += 1
                key = k
                print 'key attempt: {0:b}'.format(key)
        if(keyRank == len(dictionary)):
            print 'found key: {0:b}'.format(key)
            break
```

1. The key is 36 bits
2. I get a memory error on the `for k in range()` line of code
3. Why is this a memory issue?  Does python build an actual list of ints before running this line?  Is there a better way to write this loop?
4. I'm brand new to Python and this wouldn't be a problem in C or Java.
5. This is a known-plaintext/ciphertext attack.  dictionary is a mapping of P:C pairs.
6. Its on a VM, I can up the memory if needed, but want to know both why its failing and a code-based workaround or better idiomatic approach.

Comment: In python 2, try xrange()

Comment: Use xrange().  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 2, [range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) will build the entire list in memory.

[xrange()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) is a sequence object that evaluates lazily.

In python 3, [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does what xrange() did.

Comment: Is there any history as to why `range()` worked that way in Python2?

Comment: It has utility that way, for instance, you can use slice on the return of range(), but eventually I guess, people realized that faster and simpler was better than having that extra utility.